# Derive a formula to find the number of trailing zeroes in $n!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, factorial, decimal-expansion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How come the number $N!$ can terminate in exactly $1,2,3,4,$ or $6$ zeroes but never $5$ zeroes?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17916/how-come-the-number-n-can-terminate-in-exactly-1-2-3-4-or-6-zeroes-but-n)

I know that I have to find the number of factors of $5$'s, $25$'s, $125$'s etc. in order to do this. But how can you derive such a formula for any number $n$?

Comment: [This](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/factzero.htm) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18261/number-of-zeros-not-possible-in-n).

Answer (score 11):

The number of trailing zeroes in $n!$ is the exponent of $5$ in the prime factorization of $n!$, which by the [de Polignac's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Polignac%27s_formula)$^1$ is given by

$$e_5(n!)=\sum_{i= 1}^{\left\lfloor \log n/\log 5\right\rfloor} \left \lfloor \frac{n}{5^i} \right \rfloor.\tag{1}$$

*Added*. By the same de Polignac's formula the exponent of $2$ in the prime factorization of $n!$ is

$$e_2(n!)=\sum_{i= 1}^{\left\lfloor\log n/\log 2\right\rfloor} \left \lfloor \frac{n}{2^i} \right \rfloor.\tag{2}$$

*Edited*. For every $n$ there exists $m$ such that  $n!=2^{e_2(n!)}\cdot 5^{e_5(n!)}m=(2^{e_2(n!)-e_5(n!)}m)10^{e_5(n!)}$, which proves that the number of trailing zeroes in $n!$ is the exponent of $5$ in the prime factorization of $n!$ .

*Example*: $n=50$. The exponent of $2$ in the prime factorization of $50!$ is

$$\begin{align}
e_2(50!)=\sum_{i\geq 1}\left\lfloor \dfrac{50}{2^{i}}\right\rfloor &= \left\lfloor \dfrac{50}{2}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor \dfrac{50}{2^{2}} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \dfrac{50}{2^{3}} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\dfrac{50}{2^{4}}\right\rfloor +\left\lfloor \dfrac{50}{2^{5}}\right\rfloor
\\
&=25+12+6+3+1 
\\
&=47,
\end{align}$$

and the exponent of $5$ is  $$e_5(50!)=\sum_{i\geq 1}\left\lfloor \dfrac{50}{5^{i}}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor \dfrac{50}{5}\right\rfloor +\left\lfloor \dfrac{50}{5^{2}}\right\rfloor =10+2=12.$$
So, the number of trailing zeroes in $50!=2^{47}5^{12}m=(2^{35}m)10^{12}$ is $12$.

$^1$ *For every integer* $n$ *the exponent of the prime* $p$ *in the prime
factorization of* $n!$ *equals* $$\displaystyle\sum_{i= 1}^{\left\lfloor \log n/\log p\right\rfloor}\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^{i}}
\right\rfloor .$$

This exponent is obtained by adding to the numbers between $1$ and $n$ which are
divisible by $p$ the number of those divisible by $p^{2}$, then the number
of those divisible by $p^{3}$, and so on. The process terminates at the
greatest power $p^{i}\leq n$.

Comment: can you be a little more specific? What is k in this case? and is that the formula to find the trailing zeroes or the exponent of 5?

Comment: Dear Américo: You didn't explain what $k$ is. I'd replace it by $\infty$. (You can also replace it by $n$, or by many other expressions.)

Comment: Dear @user25329: Américo will probably answer, but in the meantime I'll tell you that Américo claims that the number of trailing zeroes equals the exponent of $5$, and that you can replace $k$ by $\infty$. (At least that's how I understand Américo's post.)

Comment: But don't we also need to take into account numbers like 25,125,625 that has multiple 5's in them? How can we take that into account and combine everything in one formula? In other words, what is the formula in terms of n that counts the number of zeros at the end of "n!"?

Comment: @user25329: I fixed it.

Comment: @ Pierre-Yves Gaillard: Thanks, you are right. I fixed the typo and added an explanation!

Comment: @AméricoTavares: I edited your post slightly (by adding '\left' and '\right' on the floor functions).  I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @JavaMan: Thanks. I now did the same for the exponent of 5.

Comment: @user25329: The formula $(1)$ takes into acount the powers of $5$ less or equal to $n$. The sum counts the number of integers between $1$ and $n$ that are multiples of $5,5^2,5^3,\dots$. The number of trailing zeroes in n! is the exponent of 5 in the prime factorization of n!, by the argument I added.

Comment: @user25329: You are welcome. I have simplified the answer and added an explanation to the footer note concerning de Polignac's formula.

Comment: @user25329: Do you need further details/explanations?

Answer (score 3):

(HINT) Let's see:

For a number up to $4$, no fives divide $n!$. Between $5$ and $9$, exactly 1 5 divides $n!$. At $10$, we get another $5$. Thinking about it, we may suspect that at $15$, we would get our next 5, and so on.

So is the formula $\lfloor \frac{n}{5} \rfloor$? That seems to work up to 5, 10, 15, 20. But at $25$, we get not 1 but two additional factors of $5$! Thus we get that for $26$ and so on, too!

How can we modify our formula to account for that?

(and - so that you don't think it's done then, remember things like $125$ and $625$ too).