# Legendre's formula for $n!$

Tags: number-theory

For what $n$ the following is true: $$\left[\dfrac{n}{5}\right]+\left[\dfrac{n}{5^2}\right]+\left[\dfrac{n}{5^3}\right]+\cdots=100$$

**My sketch:** We know that $[x]\leq x<[x]+1$ for any real $x$. Also its obvious that above sum is finite. We can estimate this sum: $$100\leq \dfrac{n}{5}+\dfrac{n}{5^2}+\cdots=\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{n}{5^k}=n/4$$
Hence $n>400$.

I check this out on the computer and yielded that it's true for $n\in \{405, 406, 407, 408,409\}$. Why my estimate is wrong?

Comment: Why do you say your estimate wrong? It seems right enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your estimate is not accurate because:

**You should change this:**

$$\color\red{100\leq\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{n}{5^k}=n/4}$$

**To this:**

$$\color\green{100=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\log_5n}\left\lfloor\dfrac{n}{5^k}\right\rfloor<\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\log_5n}\dfrac{n}{5^k}<\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{n}{5^k}=n/4}$$

---

Keep in mind that we are dealing with positive integers here.

Therefore $k>\log_5n\implies5^k>n\implies\dfrac{n}{5^k}<1\implies\left\lfloor\dfrac{n}{5^k}\right\rfloor=0$.

Comment: I already meant this but I forgot mention it. Anyway your remark does not lead to a correct estimate. Am I right?

Comment: @RFZ: You are trying to find the minimum value of $n$ such that the multiplicity of $5$ in $n$ is $100$, right? The formula for that is $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\log_5n}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{5^k}\right\rfloor$, not $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{5^k}$.

Comment: @RFZ: No, it does not. It merely tries to explain why your estimate of $n=400$ is not accurate.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It became much better

Comment: @RFZ: You're welcome. I've expanded the explanation a little bit.

Comment: That's great! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Your estimate is not wrong. You estimated $n>400$. And it is true for $n=405, 406, 407, 408, 409$.

They all satisfy $n>400$.

Comment: Ok! But how to get the five numbers which satisfy above indentity?

Comment: Maybe my estimate is not wrong but it's too rough right?

Comment: @R.F.Z See the related question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163388/given-number-of-trailing-zeros-in-n-find-out-the-possible-values-of-n).

Comment: @RFZ yeah. That is what it is.

Answer (score 1):

From the initial estimate $n=400$, known to be a lower bound, write

$$\left[\dfrac{400+m}{5}\right]+\left[\dfrac{400+m}{5^2}\right]+\left[\dfrac{400+m}{5^3}\right]+\cdots=80+\left[\dfrac{m}{5}\right]+16+\left[\dfrac{m}{5^2}\right]+3+\left[\dfrac{25+m}{5^3}\right]+\left[\dfrac{400+m}{5^4}\right]++\left[\dfrac{400+m}{5^5}\right]+\cdots=100.$$

So you need

$$\left[\dfrac{m}{5}\right]+\left[\dfrac{m}{5^2}\right]+\left[\dfrac{25+m}{5^3}\right]+\left[\dfrac{400+m}{5^4}\right]+\left[\dfrac{400+m}{5^5}\right]+\cdots=1,$$

which is achieved for $\left[\dfrac m5\right]=1$, by inspection (for all $m$ such that $\left[\dfrac m5\right]\le1$, all terms but the first vanish).

Comment: You third term seems suspicious since $\left[\dfrac{400+m}{5^3}\right]=\left[\dfrac{375+25+m}{5^3}\right]=3+\left[\dfrac{25+m}{5^3}\right]$. Right?

Comment: Quite right, fixing. This doesn't change the conclusion. By the way, I am giving a complete solution.