# Determine the largest power of 10 that is a factor of $50!\,$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factoring

How would one find the largest power of 10 which is a factor of $50!\,{}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As ncmathsadist says, it is the number of the 5's (i.e. there are more than enough 2's).  The fives come from 5, 10, 15, 20, ..., 50.  One five comes from each totaling 10, and 25 and 50 give you an extra, so the total would be 12.

Comment: yes because 50 (5*5*2) and 25 (5*5) so 25 has two factor of five while the rest have at least one.

Comment: @FernandoMartinez, Exactly.  Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 3):

It is the same as the largest power of 5 that is a factor of $50!$

Comment: Is this because $5*2=10$ but $50!$ has large number of multiples of 2?

Comment: yes.  Every factor of five has a surfeit of powers of 2 to "mate with" to produce a factor of 10.

Answer (score 2):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/590901), it is shown that the number of factors of a prime $p$ that divide $n!$ is
$$
\frac{n-\sigma_p(n)}{p-1}
$$
where $\sigma_p(n)$ is the sum of the digits of $n$ written in base-$p$.

The number of factors of $10$ that divide $50!$ is the number of factors of $5$ that divide it (there are over twice as many factors of $2$).  $50=200_\text{five}$ so $\sigma_5(50)=2$ and the number of factors of $5$ that divide $50!$ is
$$
\frac{50-2}{5-1}=12
$$

---

We could also compute the number of factors of $2$ that divide $50!$: $50=110010_\text{two}$ so $\sigma_2(50)=3$ and the number of factors of $2$ that divide $50!$ is
$$
\frac{50-3}{2-1}=47
$$
Thus, there are enough factors of $2$ to match the number of factors of $5$. This ensures that the number of factors of $10$ in $50!$ is $12$.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is equivalent to find the number of trailing zeros in $n!=50!$. I adapt [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/111390/752) to the question [*Derive a formula to find the number of trailing zeroes in $n!$*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111385/derive-a-formula-to-find-the-number-of-trailing-zeroes-in-n).

*For every integer* $n$ *the exponent of the prime* $p$ *in the prime
factorization of* $n!$ *is given by [de Polignac's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Polignac%27s_formula)* $$\displaystyle\sum_{i\ge 1}\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^{i}}
\right\rfloor =\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^2}\right\rfloor+\cdots+\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^k}\right\rfloor ,\qquad p^k\le n,\ p^{k+1}\gt n.$$

because this exponent is obtained by adding to the numbers between $1$ and $n$ which are
divisible by $p$ the number of those divisible by $p^{2}$, then the number
of those divisible by $p^{3}$, and so on. The process terminates at the
greatest power $p^{i}\leq n$.

For $n=50$ the exponent of $5$ in in the prime factorization of $50!$ is  $$e_5(50!)=\sum_{i\geq 1}\left\lfloor \dfrac{50}{5^{i}}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor \dfrac{50}{5}\right\rfloor +\left\lfloor \dfrac{50}{5^{2}}\right\rfloor =10+2=12<47.$$

Similarly the exponent of $2$ in the prime factorization of $50!$ is

$$\begin{align}
e_2(50!)=\sum_{i\geq 1}\left\lfloor \dfrac{50}{2^{i}}\right\rfloor &= \left\lfloor \dfrac{50}{2}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor \dfrac{50}{2^{2}} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \dfrac{50}{2^{3}} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\dfrac{50}{2^{4}}\right\rfloor +\left\lfloor \dfrac{50}{2^{5}}\right\rfloor
\\
&=25+12+6+3+1 
\\
&=47>12.
\end{align}$$

So $50!=2^{47}5^{12}m=(2^{35}m)10^{12}$, with $\gcd(m,10)=1$, as pointed out by robjohn. Consequently, the number of trailing zeroes in $50!$ is $12$ and the power is $10^{12}$.

Comment: more precisely $(m,10)=1$.

Comment: @robjohn Thanks! I've corrected the answer.