# Factorial question: number of trailing zeroes in 125!

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, divisibility, factorial, decimal-expansion

How many zeros are after the last nonzero digit of 125! ?

The answer is 31, but how do you solve it?

Comment: The question is asking you to find the highest power of ten dividing
$$125! = 125 \cdot 124 \cdot 123 \cdot \cdots \cdot 2 \cdot 1.$$
So count how many copies of $2$ and $5$ there are, then take the minimum.

Comment: You can find several similar questions on this site. See [Derive a formula to find the number of trailing zeroes in $n!$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111385/derive-a-formula-to-find-the-number-of-trailing-zeroes-in-n) and maybe some other questions tagged [decimal-expansion+factorial](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decimal-expansion+factorial)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Well, we know that to have a zero at the end then $10$ must be a factor, which means $5$ and $2$ must be factors. However, every other factor is even, so there are far more factors of $2$ than $5$ - As such, we have to count the number of factors divisible by $5$. The number of factors divisible by $5$ less than or equal to $125$ is $25$ (we just do $\frac{125}{5}$), so the answer appears to be $25$, but then we remember that $25 = 5\cdot5$, so we must count double for each factor divisible by $25$, of which there are $5$; accordingly, our new answer is $30$. BUT WAIT... $125 = 5^3$, so we have to count it too, giving us a final answer of $31$

Answer (score 9):

The formula explaining above:
$$\text{Number of zeros in }n!=\left[ \frac {n}{5} \right]+\left[ \frac {n}{5^2} \right]+\ldots $$ where [.] denotes the greatest integer  function.

Answer (score 3):

Note that if there is at least one zero after the last non-zero digit of $125!$, then $125!$ is divisible by $10$. Likewise, if there are two, then $125!$ is divisible by $100$, etc.. Thus, we need to check how many times $125!$ is divisible by $10$.

> So, we count the multiples of $5^1$, $5^2$, and $5^3 = 125$, in $125!$. It is easy to see that there are $25 = 125/5$ factors divisible by $5^1 = 5$, less than $125$. Similarly, there are $ 5 = 125/25 $ factors divisible by $5^2 = 25$ in $125$. And finally, there is $1 = 125/125$ factors divisible by $5^3 = 125$. Thus, by the sum rule, there are $25 + 5 + 1 = 31$ such factors. But, this counts the number of times $125!$ is divisible by $10$, since $10 = 5 \times 2$, and there is a $2$ in the prime decomposition of $125!$.

Answer (score -1):

I just count them.

125! = 188267717688892609974376770249160085759540364871492425887598231508353156331613598866882932889495923133646405445930057740630161919341380597818883457558547055524326375565007131770880000000000000000000000000000000

Have a Apple computer? Compute the value yourself. Below is the applescript. Paste into the Script Editor application and click on the "Run the Script" button.

```
on ids(digits as text)
    if digits is "" or digits is not "0" and digits starts with "0" then error "bad integer " & digits
    set x to (id of digits) as list
    repeat with digit in x
        if digit < 48 or digit > 57 then error "bad integer"
    end repeat
    return x
end ids

on add(x as text, y as text)
    set {a, b, n, carry} to {ids(x), ids(y), (length of x) - (length of y), 0}
    if n < 0 then set {a, b, n} to {b, a, -n}
    repeat with i from length of a to 1 by -1
        set {carry, sum, j} to {0, carry + (item i of a), i - n}
        if j > 0 then set sum to sum + (item j of b) - 48
        if sum > 57 then set {carry, sum} to {1, sum - 10}
        set item i of a to sum
    end repeat
    if carry > 0 then set beginning of a to carry + 48
    return character id a
end add

on multiply(x as text, y as text)
    set {a, b, c, sum} to {ids(x), ids(y), {}, "0"}
    repeat with m from length of b to 1 by -1
        set multiplier to (item m of b) - 48
        if multiplier is not 0 and x is not "0" then
            set carry to 0
            repeat with i from length of a to 1 by -1
                set product to carry + ((item i of a) - 48) * multiplier
                set carry to product div 10
                set beginning of c to product mod 10 + 48
            end repeat
            if carry > 0 then set beginning of c to carry + 48
            set sum to add(sum, character id c)
        end if
        set end of c to 48
        set c to items (m - (length of b) - 1) thru end of c
    end repeat
    return sum
 end multiply

 set x to 1
 repeat with y from 1 to 125
    set x to multiply(x, y)
 end repeat
```

Comment: Python: `import math; digits = str(math.factorial(125)); print(len(digits) - len(digits.rstrip('0')))`.

Comment: Could you run that script and tell us the number of trailing zeroes in $125000!$?