# Trying to find a recursive solution.

Tags: computer-science, recursion

**Problem statement**:  Find the number of trailing zeros in the decimal representation of N!.

You can find the actual problem statement [here](http://www.spoj.com/problems/FCTRL/).

Here is what I tried :

```
       #include <stdio.h>
       int fct(int n);
       int main(void)
        {

          int n,t;
          scanf("%d",&t);
          while(t-- > 0) 
          {
           scanf("%d",&n);
           printf("%d\n",fct(n)-n);
          }
          return 0;
         }
        int fct(int n)
        {
          static int s=0;
           if(n<5)
            return s+n;
           else
          {
           s=fct(n/5);
           s=s+n;
           return s;
          }
       }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. My above recursive function does'nt return the actual answer and I was not able write a function that returns the actual answer(number of trailing zeroes). Hence I needed some help in doing so. 
I think the program I posted below does that.

Comment: Your question should be formulated thus: "find the number of trailing zeros in the decimal representation of $N!$".

Comment: My bad . Editing the question now.

Comment: An interesting answer :(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23977727/the-number-of-trailing-zeros-in-a-factorial-of-a-given-number-ruby)

Comment: Besides, are you aware that there exist a formula: "de Polignac formula" for getting the answer in a direct, non recurrent, way. See the answer in (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/111385).

Comment: I'd definitely suggest changing $\texttt{int}$ to $\texttt{long}$ to avoid overflow problems (since $N$ may be as large as $10^9$).

Comment: Usually ( in a numerical area ), we calculate $\ln\left(n!\right)$ instead of $n!$. $n!$ is recovered with $\exp\left(\ln\left(n!\right)

Comment: @JeanMarie I have already submitted an iterative one . I want to learn recursion hence I'm trying to solve this problem recursively.

Comment: Usually ( in a numerical area ), we calculate $\ln\left(n!\right)$ instead of $n!$. $n!$ is recovered with $\texttt{(unsigned long long)(exp(logFactorial(n) + 0.5))}$ where $\texttt{logFactorial}$ is a $\texttt{C function}$. By the way, $\texttt{C++}$ [already implements](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/lgamma/) $\ln\left(\Gamma\left(z\right)\right)$.

Comment: What is the question? How to write cleaner code? That would be off-topic here, such questions would belong on [codereview.se] (but would need to be clearly stated). How to make it more efficient? Ditto. If the question is about the mathematical aspects of the algorithm, that would be on-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   int fct(int n);
```

That should be "static int fct(int n)".  The static represents that the name fct has file scope, rather than the scope of the entire linked project.

```
   int main(void)
    {
     int n,t;
      scanf("%d",&t);
      while(t-- > 0)
```

Don't mix persistent and functional behavior, even though C lets you.  I suggest:

```
      int t;
      for (scanf("%d", &t); t > 0; t--) {
```

because it is a lot less confusing.

```
      {
       scanf("%d",&n);
       printf("%d\n",fct(n)-n);
```

Why are you calculating Z(n) + n?  Why not just calculate Z(n) directly?  Are you trying to make this hard on yourself?

```
      }
      return 0;
    }

    int fct(int n)
```

Don't name things fct.  The english language has a lot of words in it.  Learn to use them.  Also, this function should be tagged as static to indicate that it has file scope rather than global scope.

```
    {
      static int s=0;
```

Don't make local variables static.  It puts them in "static memory" rather than making a new variable on the stack, making your function only work once, then fail forever more.

```
       if(n<5) return s+n;
       else {
         s=fct(n/5);
         s=s+n;
         return s;
       }
   }
```

Again, why this misery of trying to calculate Z(n) + n rather than just Z(n) ?

It appears what you are trying to implement tail recursion.  Tail recursion is a type of recursion where the return value is passed on the stack as a parameter.  You are avoiding the stack by using a static variable, which breaks everything, but effecting you are creating a helper function like:

```
int Z(n) {
  return Z2(n, 0);
}

int Z2(n, s) {
  if (...) {
    return s;
  }
  else {
    return ...Z(...n..., ...s...);
  }
}
```

Trying to learn tail recursion before you can do regular recursion is a bad idea.  Just write it like:

```
int Z(n) {
  if (...) {
    return ...;
  }
  else {
    return ...Z(...n...)...;
  }
}
```

That said, since you are trying to implement it recursively, rather than as effeciently as possible, try to implement this:

```
   Sum = 0
   For each value from 1..n divisible by 5, add 1 to sum
   For each value from 1..n divisible by 25, add 1 to sum
   For each value from 1..n divisible by 125, add 1 to sum
   For each value from 1..n divisible by 625, add 1 to sum
   etc
   return sum
```

Try to implement that by starting by checking n, then recurring on Z(n - 1).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks DanielIV for breaking the problem down.

Here is my working recursive solution which got accepted in SPOJ.

```
       #include <stdio.h>
       int factorial(int n);

       int main(void)
     {

       int t,n;

       for(scanf("%d",&t);t > 0;--t ) {
       scanf("%d",&n);
       printf("%d\n",factorial(n));
       }
       return 0;
     }

   int factorial(int n)
   {
   if(n<1)
   return 0;
   return (n/5 + factorial(n/5));
   }
```