# What is longer? Length of $2^n$ or number of $0$ in $n!$?

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, factorial

What is longer? Length of $2^n$ or number of $0$ at the end of $n!$ ?
Assume that $n$ is really big, big number...

### Solution

Look at terms of $2^k$:
$$2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048,4096... $$
It can be seen that 
$$ \lfloor\frac{n}{3} \rfloor \ge length(2^n)\ge \lfloor\frac{n}{4} \rfloor   $$

Now, lets look at $n!$. We know that $0$ is created at the end iif we use $2$ and $5$ or $10$. Number of $2$ is greater than number of $5$ so  we can count number of $5$.

$$\mbox{number of 0 in } n! = \sum_{k \ge 0} \lfloor\frac{n}{10^k} \rfloor +   \sum_{k \ge 0} \lfloor \frac{n}{5^k} \rfloor  $$

$$ (n-1)\left(  \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{1}{10^k}  +   \sum_{k \ge 0}  \frac{1}{5^k}   \right)\ge \mbox{number of 0 in } n! \ge n \left(  \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{1}{10^k}  +   \sum_{k \ge 0}  \frac{1}{5^k}   \right) $$
$$ \mbox{number of 0 in } n! \approx \frac{13}{36} \cdot n \approx 0.361 \cdot n \ge \frac{1}{3} \cdot n $$

So the longer is  number of $0$ in $n!$. Have I done this exercise correctly?

### update

$$ (n-1)\left(    \sum_{k \ge 0}  \frac{1}{5^k}   \right)\ge \mbox{number of 0 in } n! \ge n \left(  \sum_{k \ge 0}  \frac{1}{5^k}   \right) $$
$$ \mbox{number of 0 in } n! \le 1/4 $$ so length of 2^n is greater that trailing $0$ in $n!$

Comment: You're counting the zeros only in the least significant digits? Correct?

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111385/derive-a-formula-to-find-the-number-of-trailing-zeroes-in-n?noredirect=1&lq=1) for the formula. You mean trailing zeroes, right?

Comment: Yes @dfnu, it comes for the zeros at the end of $n!$

Comment: Did you try any examples?  $2^{30}$ has $10$ digits, but $30!$ ends in only $7$ zeroes. $2^{100}$ has $31$ digits but $100!$ ends is $24$ zeroes.

Comment: I tried @lulu and got similar results but I believe that in really big numbers, $n!$  wins, but I am not sure so I posted that here. Also $n=100$ is not a big number. I think that for big number we can consider something like $ n= 10^{10000000000000000000} $ but it also can be greater. It is realtive

Comment: Where do you assume large $n$ in your argument?  What does the conclusion $n≥\frac 13$ mean?

Comment: It would be better to consider $\log_{10}2$ than to say, "It can be seen that ..."

Comment: corrected @lulu

Comment: Again, it's not clear where you are using the assumption of large $n$.  For $n=100$ it is not true that the number of trailing zeroes in $100!$ exceeds $\frac {100}3$.  I just checked $n=10^9$ and $2^n$ is still longer.  It is true that the ratio of the two is declining, but I don't see how you've proven the desired claim.

Comment: An obvious upper bound on the number of trailing zeroes, $F(n)$, is given by dropping the floor function and summing the infinite geometric series.  We get $F(n)≤\frac n4$.  I expect that this is quite accurate for (very) large $n$.

Comment: I use assumption of large $n$ when dropping floor function

Comment: As I say, dropping the floor function gives you an upper bound, not a lower bound.  And It gives $\frac n4$, not $\frac n3$.  But the key point is that it isn't instantly clear that an upper bound helps you here.  In any case, I think you have more work to do.

Comment: Did you read my solution? I wrote upper and lower bound.

Comment: I only read the conclusion, which says that the number of trailing zeroes in $n!$ is $≥\frac n3$.  That conclusion is wrong, so I didn't look at the details.

Comment: You shouldn't separately sum over powers of 10 and powers of 5. You care about the number of times the factor 5 appears. 10 is not exactly relevant here (just like 15 and 20 are not).

Comment: Furthermore as written, you claim that $n - 1 \geq n$. But either way I think your lower bound either does not work or requires a more thorough argument.

Comment: "You shouldn't separately sum over powers of 10 and powers of 5. You care about the number of times the factor 5 appears. 10 is not exactly relevant here (just like 15 and 20 are not). " It is really helpful. I updated post. Can you look currently at that? Also, can you past that as answer? I want to mark that as the best. @MeesdeVries

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Denote by $l(n)$ the number of digits of $2^n$ and by $t(n)$ the number of trailing zeros of $n!$. We aim to show that $t(n) < l(n)$, at least for large $n$.

Per the update, the number of trailing zeros in $n!$ is the number of factors of $5$ in the prime factorization of $n!$, and it [follows from the definition of factorial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141196/highest-power-of-a-prime-p-dividing-n) that this is
$$t(n) = \sum_{k \geq 0} \left\lfloor\frac{n}{5^k}\right\rfloor .$$

The definition of $\lfloor \,\cdot\, \rfloor$ implies that $\lfloor m \rfloor \leq m$, so (as nearly observed in the question statement) $$t(n) \leq \sum_{k \geq 0} \frac{n}{5^k} = n \sum_{k \geq 0} \frac{1}{5^k} = \frac{1}{4} n .$$

To make rigorous the rest of the argument, we should formalize the assertion "It can be seen that..." as an inequality and then use it to show that $t(n) < l(n)$.

**Hint** To do this, we can use a [familiar formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231742/proof-how-many-digits-does-a-number-have-lfloor-log-10-n-rfloor-1) $$l(n) = \lfloor \log_{10} (2^n) \rfloor + 1 = \lfloor n \log_{10} 2 \rfloor + 1 .$$
The definition of $\lfloor \,\cdot\, \rfloor$ implies that $m \leq \lfloor m \rfloor + 1$, immediately giving the lower bound
$$(\log_{10} 2) n \leq l(n) .$$

> Comparing our bounds, we can see that if we can show $$\phantom{(\ast)} \qquad \frac{1}{4} < \log_{10} 2 , \qquad (\ast)$$ then we will have $$t(n) \leq \frac{1}{4} n < (\log_{10} 2) n \leq l(n)$$ as desired (in fact, for all $n > 0$, not just large $n$). But some algebraic rearrangement shows that $(\ast)$ is equivalent to $10 < 16$.

Comment: Yeah, that’s the answer! If you guys don’t know why is $\dfrac{1}{4}<\log_{10} 2$ equivalent to $10<16$, I will show you guys. Firstly, we take $\log_{10}$ both side of $10<16$ and get $1<\log_{10}{16}$. Observe that $\log_{10}{16}=4\log_{10} 2$. Then, divide both sides by 4 and we’ll get $\dfrac{1}{4}<\log_{10} 2$

Comment: @IsaacYIUMathStudio Thanks for the elaboration. It's not true for all number bases $b$, by the way, that the number $t(n)$ of trailing zeros of $n!$ in base $b$ is smaller (for large $n$) than the number $l(n)$ of base-$b$ digits of $2^n$. For example, in base $6$, $t(n) = \frac{1}{2} n + o(n)$ but $l(n) = (\log_6 2) n + o(n)$, and $\log_6 2 = 0.38685\ldots < \frac{1}{2}$. A problem you might find interesting is to find the base for which this case is the most extreme, that is, find the base for which the limiting value $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{t(n) - l(n)}{n}$ is the largest.