# calculate number of terminating zeroes in n!! double factorial

Tags: factorial

How do I calculate the number of terminating zeroes in $n!!$

$$ n!!=\prod _{k=0}^{\left\lceil {\frac {n}{2}}\right\rceil -1}(n-2k)=n(n-2)(n-4)\cdots $$

where : $n!!$ is defined as double factorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clearly, we can see that $n!!$ cannot have any trailing zeroes if n is odd because there is no multiplier of $2$ in the product.
as

$$n!! = \prod_{k = 0}^{ \bigl\lceil \frac{n}{2}\bigr\rceil - 1} (n - 2k)$$

also, we can write

$$n! = n!! \times (n - 1)!!$$

$$ n!!={\frac {n!}{(n-1)!!}}={\frac {(n+1)!}{(n+1)!!}}$$

where the denominator cancels the unwanted factors in the numerator. (The last form also applies when n = 0.)
For an even non-negative integer $n = 2k$ with $k \ge 0$, the double factorial may be expressed as

$$n!! = 2^k k!$$
now we just need to find the number of trailing zeroes in $k = \frac{n}{2}$
i.e.

$$\text{Trailing Zeroes} = \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} \Biggl\lfloor\frac{n}{2 . 5^{i}}\Biggr\rfloor = \Biggl\lfloor\frac {n}{2 . 5} \Biggr\rfloor+\Biggl\lfloor \frac {n}{2 . 5^2} \Biggr\rfloor+\ldots $$

- source: [Derive a formula to find the number of trailing zeroes in $n!$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111385/derive-a-formula-to-find-the-number-of-trailing-zeroes-in-n)
- wiki: [Double Factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial)

Answer (score 0):

The number of trailing zeros for even $n$ is tabulated in [A027868](https://oeis.org/A027868), which also quotes the formula with the sum of the floor-functions and provides references.