# Concecutive last zeroes in expansion of $100!$

Tags: number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Highest power of a prime $p$ dividing $N!$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141196/highest-power-of-a-prime-p-dividing-n)

In decimal form, the number $100!$ ends in how many consecutive zeroes. I am thinking of the factorization of $100!$ but I am stuck. I try to count them and since there are 10, 20, 30,..., 100, there are at least 11 zeros. How should I proceed.

Comment: And also this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17916/how-come-the-number-n-can-terminate-in-exactly-1-2-3-4-or-6-zeroes-but-n/17917#17917

Comment: See also this nice answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/216002/28900

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
2\text{ goes into }100 & & 50\text{ times} \\
2^2\text{ goes into }100 & & 25\text{ times} \\
2^3\text{ goes into }100 & & 12\text{ times} \\
2^4\text{ goes into }100 & & 6\text{ times} \\
2^5\text{ goes into }100 & & 2\text{ times} \\
2^6\text{ goes into }100 & & 1\text{ time} \\
\end{align}
$$
50+25+12+6+2+1 = 96.
$$

Thus $2^{96}$ divides $100!$ and $2^{97}$ does not.

\begin{align}
5\text{ goes into }100 & & 20\text{ times} \\
5^2\text{ goes into }100 & & 4\text{ times}
\end{align}

Thus $5^{24}$ divides $100!$ and $5^{25}$ does not.

$$\min\{96,24\}=24.$$

So $(2\cdot5)^{24}$ divides $100!$ and $(2\cdot5)^{25}$ does not.

Answer (score 0):

You want to know the highest power of $10$ that goes into $100!$, so figure out the highest power of $5$ that goes into $100!$.  To do this, think:

1) How many integers between $1$ and $100$ are multiples of $5$ ?

2) How many integers between $1$ and $100$ are multiples of $25$ ?