# How many $0$'s are at the end of $(38!)^{20}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial

I am getting $160$ as my answer but in the book, it is $168$. Which is the correct answer?

Comment: $168$ cannot be right because it is not a multiple of $20$.

Comment: Also a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/215999/11619) and friends.

Comment: Most be a typo.  As Gae S say however many $0$s $38!$ ends with (so that $38! = M*10^k$ and $10\not\mid M$) then $(38!)^{20}$ will have $20$ times as many.  $(38!)^{20}=M^{20}*10^{20k}$.  And that can't be $168$.  ...As there are $7$ multiples of $5$ up to $38$ and one of them is $25$ we have $8$ is the highest power of $5$ to divide $38!$ and as there are more multiples of $2$s than of $5$s, $8$ is the highest power of $10$ and $20*8 =160$.  You are doing it right and the book has a typo.

Comment: It would improve your Question to include the full problem statement in the body of the Question, not only in the title.

Answer (score 7):

$160$ is the correct answer!

Proof)
$$
\newcommand{\floor}[2]{\left\lfloor\frac{#1}{#2}\right\rfloor}
\floor{38}{5}
+\floor{38}{5^2}
= 7 + 1
$$

Hence, $8 \times 20 = 160$.

Answer (score 3):

Your answer of $160$ is correct.

This is because $38!$ has $8$ trailing zeros. Take this to the twentieth power and you end up with $20\times8=160$ trailing zeros.