# The Number of The 0's in a Factorial

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, factorial, decimal-expansion, parity

I need to find that the number of the 0's **at the end of the number** is odd or even in a factorial.

For example:

$0! = 1$ (Even)
$5! = 120 $ (Odd)
$18! = 6402373705728000 $ (Odd)

Dou you have any idea about this problem?

Comment: look at answers of this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286947/number-of-zero-digits-in-factorials)

Comment: I want the # of 0's at the end of the result.

Comment: That will be much easier, just count the number of $5$ in your $n!$ using [De Polignac's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Polignac%27s_formula). i.e $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor \frac{\log n}{\log 5}\right\rfloor} \left\lfloor \frac{n}{5^k} \right\rfloor$$.

Comment: Thanks. I have another question, from $1$ to $n$ how many numbers have even # of 0's? $(0!,1!, .... , n!)$