# Counting the number of zeros

Tags: number-theory

I am stuck at the question:

How many zeros are there when numbers between 1 and 100 are multiplied including 1 and 100, devise some technique for this .

Regards

Comment: Do you mean trailing zeroes? If so, it's fairly easy. If not, it's hard work $-$ you have to do the arithmetic.

Comment: yes the trailing zeros

Comment: This is a duplicate by any account: [Here for the non-trailing](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286947/number-of-zero-digits-in-factorials?rq=1), and [here for trailing zeros](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141196/highest-power-of-a-prime-p-dividing-n)

Answer (score 1):

This is asking, what is the highest power of 10, that divides 100! . This is same as the highest power of 5 that divides 100! (why?) , which is given by: [100/5] + [100/5^2] + [100/5^3] + ... = 20 + 4 = 24. This is the de Polignac's Formula.

Answer (score 1):

A number ends with an additionnal 0 iff it is multiplied by 5 and 2.

In your product, there are many more times 
'$\times$ 2' than '$\times$ 5', hence you can only counts the 5s.

Do not forget to count 2 5s for the multiples of $5\times 5$ (there are no higher powers since 5$\times$5$\times$5>100).

It gives: 20 + 4 = 24 zeros.