# Last $500$ digits of $2015!-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial, decimal-expansion

As the title says, I'm looking for the last $500$ digits of $2015!-1$. I assume it's a repetition of zeroes from the factorial, so the final result is a lot of $9$-s, but I can't formulate a solution in a mathematical way. I know that $201$ zeroes come from $10$-s in there, also, $202$ from the $5$-s that are multiplied by even numbers, $20$ extra from the $100$-s, $2$ more from the $1000$-s, but I'm still missing a couple.

Comment: How many times can $5$ divide into $2015!$?

Comment: Are you sure that's all? How about $25$?

Comment: I'd say that 2015! has 486 zeroes at the end, but the rest of the 14 numbers you ask, are the difficult part

Comment: @Nikunj $2015!$ has exactly $502$ zeroes at the end.

Comment: [Legendre's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula) solves this. It's essentially what Snow did in the answer.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286947/number-of-zero-digits-in-factorials

Comment: @user236182 yes you're right!(I forgot to divide by 125), but then shouldn't all 500 of the last numbers of 2015!-1 be 9's?

Comment: @Nikunj There are exactly $502$ nines at the end of $2015!-1$.

Comment: @user236182 yes, but the problem asks only about the last 500 digits

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are 403 numbers between 1 and 2015 are divisible by 5. Not all of them contribute just one factor of 5.

The multiples of 25 contribute two factors of 5 (there are 80 such). We already have 483 factors of 5.

A further 16 numbers are divisible by 125 and they contribute yet another factor of 5. We're now up to 499 factors of 5.

Finally, the multiples of 625 contribute yet another factor, and there are 3 such numbers. So we have at least 502 factors of 5 in 2015!. (There are in fact exactly 502 factors, but that's not important here).

There is no dearth of factors of 2, which occur more often than the factors of 5. So we know that $10^{502}$ divides 2015!. I think you know what to do from here!

Comment: @user236182, indeed. Thank you!

Comment: We have exactly (not at least) $502$ factors of $5$ in $2015!$.

Comment: @user236182, Yes, that is true, but I have not verified that above. Of course, the next power of 5 is larger than 2015, but we don't really care about that in this context. You're right, maybe I should mention this.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by user236182, [Legendre's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula), proven in $(3)$ of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/590901), says that for any prime $p$, the number of factors of $p$ in $n!$ is
$$
\frac{n-\sigma_p(n)}{p-1}
$$
where $\sigma_p(n)$ is the sum of the digits in the base-$p$ representation of $n$.

Since $2015_{\text{ten}}=31030_{\text{five}}$, the sum of the base $5$ digits is $7$ so the number of powers of $5$ in $2015!$ is
$$
\frac{2015-7}{5-1}=502
$$
There are more factors of $2$ so there are $502$ trailing zeroes for $2015!$. Therefore, the last $500$ digits of $2015!-1$ are all nines.

Comment: This uses one of the [Legendre's Formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula).

Answer (score 0):

The following formula denotes the number of times that a prime factor $p$ appears in $n!$:

$$C_{n}(p)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^k}\right\rfloor$$

---

Since $\lfloor\log_{\color\green{2}}2015\rfloor=\color\red{10}$:

$$C_{2015}(\color\green{2})=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\color\red{10}}\left\lfloor\frac{2015}{\color\green{2}^k}\right\rfloor=2005$$

---

Since $\lfloor\log_{\color\green{5}}2015\rfloor=\color\red{4}$:

$$C_{2015}(\color\green{5})=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\color\red{4}}\left\lfloor\frac{2015}{\color\green{5}^k}\right\rfloor=502$$

---

Let $Z_{n}$ denote the number of trailing zeros in the decimal representation of $n!$:

$$Z_{n}=\min\{C_{n}(2),C_{n}(5)\}$$

---

So $Z_{2015}=\min\{2005,502\}=502$, and therefore $2015!$ ends with $502$ zeros.

Since $2015!$ ends with $502$ zeros, the last $502$ digits of $2015!-1$ are all nines.