# Number of zero digits of $\frac{41!}{100}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, factorial

Let's consider a factorial number $\frac{41!}{100}$. How can we find how many digits are zero starting from the last digit of the number?

If we multiply the factorial by $100$, then the number of $0$ digits increases by $2$ and we can work with $41!$ directly. We're looking for the largest $k$ such that

$$41!\equiv 0\pmod{10^k}$$

Furthermore, since $41!$ contains $2$ and $5$, a trailling zero exists. But I am not certain as to what can be done. Could you provide a feedback?

Comment: Find the number of trailing zeros of $41!$ (by counting all the times $5$ contributes to the product), and subtract $2$.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. FYI, I suspect you'll find [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula) to be useful here, but especially so when dealing with larger factorial numbers.

Comment: @EkeneE. Why subtract $2$? Don't you just count the number of times $10$ divides the $41!$ and since $2$ occurs much more as a factor than $5$, you just count the number of times $5$ divides the product right?

Comment: @VincentBatens I've added an answer below.

Comment: @VincentBatens Subtracting $2$ accounts for dividing by $100$.  There are two related questions appearing in the question

Comment: @BrianMoehring Ah thank you, I apparently didn't read it carefully enough and didn't consider the dividing by $100$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the number of trailing zeros in $n!$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1806642/find-the-number-of-trailing-zeros-in-n) Please look for related posts on this site before (or instead of) posting a duplicate question.

Answer (score 5):

By Legendre's formula the number of trailing zeros of $41!$ is
$$\nu_5(41!) = \left\lfloor \frac{41}{5} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{41}{25} \right\rfloor = 9,$$
and dividing $41!$ by $100$ takes off two of those zeros, so there are $7$ trailing zeros.

Comment: you should mention trailing zeros require factors of 2 and 5, just that there's more factors of 2 in this case.

Comment: Please don't post an answer to such a FAQ. Instead, look for a good duplicate target.