# Finding all the zeroes in $100!$

Tags: factorial, decimal-expansion

Is there a way to find all the $0$s in $100!$? (Including zeroes that come between two non-zero numbers)

I know that to find the $0$s at the end we can use the greatest integer method. I was just curious if a method exists to find the remaining zeroes, too. (Of course **without** finding the actual value of $100!$ and counting, as is done in the only answer to this previous question: [How many zeroes are in 100!](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/142126/8348).)

Comment: The duplicate did not answer the question.......

Comment: What John said. The other similar question did not get a proper answer. I'm not sure how this should be handled though.

Comment: There was no need to post a new question, as this ask *exactly* the same as the old one!

Comment: What does *finding* all zeroes mean. Do you mean finding number of them and also positions?

Comment: Related post: [Number of zero digits in factorials](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286947/number-of-zero-digits-in-factorials)

Answer (score 1):

One way is to compute it!

```
In[2]:= Count[IntegerDigits[100!], 0]
Out[2]= 30
```

This computation took 0.000033 seconds in Mathematica.

Comment: (I seriously doubt there is a better way)

Comment: The sequence $2, 30, 472, 5803, 68620, 782336, \dots$ is the number of zero digits in $10^k!$ starting from $k=1$. This is [not](http://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C+30%2C+472%2C+5803%2C+68620%2C+782336&language=english&go=Search) in the OEIS (yet?). The next one, $10^7!$, has something like $1.5\times 10^8$ digits, and probably one needs to do something smarter than my trivial code above to compute the number of zeroes.