# How many zeroes are there at the end of $36!^{36!}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, factorial

Could you please tell me how many zeroes are there at the end of $36!$ to the power $36!$, i.e., $36!^{36!}$? I have been trying to find out. Read some reviews and answers related this but didn't understand at all. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The number of trailing zeroes of 36! equals the number of $5$'s that divide $36!$, which can be computed with [De Polignac's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Polignac%27s_formula).

Comment: Been wondering the same a week ago, hope this link helps! http://www.purplemath.com/modules/factzero.htm

Comment: On a sarcastic note, if you just keep the number written as $36!^{36!}$, then the answer is zero.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How many zeroes are in 100!](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142126/how-many-zeroes-are-in-100)

Comment: @apnorton, not that simple! Its its a impossible number to the power an impossible number, making it further impossible!

Comment: @JessePFrancis Oops. I meant to delete that comment, because there's a slight difference ("in 100!" vs "at the end of 100!").  Other than that, however, the procedure is exactly the same.  (Also, be careful saying a problem is "impossible."  This problem is certainly solvable.)

Comment: It was simpler than I thought! :D

Comment: @mapierce271 *looks at $36!^{36!}$*    I see zero zeroes.

Answer (score 4):

[De Polignac's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Polignac%27s_formula) tells us that $36!$ there are 34 powers of $2$ and 8 powers of $5$, so when $36!$ is factored, there are $8$ zeros because there is a $10^8$ in its factorisation. Since each power of $36!$ adds 8 zeroes, $36!^{36!}$ has $8\cdot36!$ zeros at the end.

Answer (score 1):

$\sum\limits_{k:5^k<n}\lfloor\frac{n}{5^k}\rfloor$ gives the number of trailing zeros in n!

Above suggests that there are eight trailing zeros in 36!, so we can write $36!=\text{some number ending with non zero digit, (say k)}\times 10^8$

$\implies 36!^{36!}=(k\times 10^8)^{36!}$

We just need to be concerned about the ${10^8}^{36!}$ part since $k^{36!}$ will not contribute any more zeroes (if last digit of k$\ne0$ then last digit of $k^m\ne0\forall m\in\mathbb{N}$

And hence it has $8.36!$ trailing zeros.