# Prove that for all non-negative integers $m,n$, $\frac{(2m)!(2n)!}{m!n!(m + n)!}$ is an integer.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

> Prove that for all non-negative integers $m,n$, $\frac{(2m)!(2n)!}{m!n!(m + n)!}$ is an integer.

I'm not familiar to factorial and I don't have much idea, can someone show me how to prove this? Thank you.

Comment: Prove that the factorial ratio satisfies a two-term recurrence relation with integer coefficients and integer initial value.

Comment: I wonder if there isn't some way to make this into a product of binomial coefficients.

Comment: This was a 1972 IMO [problem](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/1972_IMO_Problems)

Comment: Is there a way to interpret this expression as counting something?

Comment: By induction is it possible ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Denote $\frac{(2m)!(2n)!}{m!n!(m + n)!}$ by $S(n,m)$. It satisfies relation $S(n+1,m)+S(n,m+1)=4S(n,m)$ (cf. Pascal's triangle) — or, equivalently, $S(n+1,m)=4S(n,m)-S(n,m+1)$. Since $S(0,m)=\binom{2m}m$ is an integer, this relation implies that all $S(n,m)$ are integers.

**Ref.:** I. Gessel. [Super Ballot Numbers](http://people.brandeis.edu/~gessel/homepage/papers/superballot.pdf) (via [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26336/integer-valued-factorial-ratios))

Answer (score 11):

Consider a prime $p$. The highest power of $p$ dividing the numerator is $$\alpha_{Nr} = \left(\left \lfloor \dfrac{2m}{p}\right \rfloor + \left \lfloor \dfrac{2m}{p^2}\right \rfloor + \left \lfloor \dfrac{2m}{p^3}\right \rfloor + \cdots \right) + \left(\left \lfloor \dfrac{2n}{p}\right \rfloor + \left \lfloor \dfrac{2n}{p^2}\right \rfloor + \left \lfloor \dfrac{2n}{p^3}\right \rfloor + \cdots \right)$$

The highest power $p$ dividing the denominator is $$\alpha_{Dr} = \left(\left \lfloor \dfrac{m}{p}\right \rfloor + \left \lfloor \dfrac{m}{p^2}\right \rfloor + \left \lfloor \dfrac{m}{p^3}\right \rfloor + \cdots \right) + \left(\left \lfloor \dfrac{n}{p}\right \rfloor + \left \lfloor \dfrac{n}{p^2}\right \rfloor + \left \lfloor \dfrac{n}{p^3}\right \rfloor + \cdots \right) + \left(\left \lfloor \dfrac{m+n}{p}\right \rfloor + \left \lfloor \dfrac{m+n}{p^2}\right \rfloor + \left \lfloor \dfrac{m+n}{p^3}\right \rfloor + \cdots \right)$$

[You may want to look at this post that discusses the highest power of a prime dividing $N!$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141196/highest-power-of-a-prime-p-dividing-n)

The goal now is to show that $\alpha_{Nr} > \alpha_{Dr}$. If we prove that $$\lfloor 2x \rfloor + \lfloor 2y \rfloor \geq \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor y \rfloor + \lfloor x+y \rfloor$$ we are then done. Can you now prove this one?

We have $x = \lfloor x \rfloor + \{x \}$ and $y = \lfloor y \rfloor + \{y \}$.

We will consider 4 cases.

**Case $1$**: $\{x\} <1/2$, $\{y\} <1/2$. Then $\lfloor 2x \rfloor = 2 \lfloor x \rfloor$ and $\lfloor 2y \rfloor = 2 \lfloor y \rfloor$ and $\lfloor x + y \rfloor = \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor y \rfloor$. Hence, we have $$\lfloor 2x \rfloor + \lfloor 2y \rfloor = \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor y \rfloor + \lfloor x+y \rfloor$$

**Case $2$**: $\{x\} <1/2$, $\{y\} >1/2$ or $\{x\} >1/2$, $\{y\} <1/2$. Then $$\lfloor 2x \rfloor + \lfloor 2y \rfloor = 2 \lfloor x \rfloor + 2 \lfloor y \rfloor + 1$$
Further, $$\lfloor x+y \rfloor \leq \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor y \rfloor + 1$$ Hence, we have $$\lfloor 2x \rfloor + \lfloor 2y \rfloor = \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor y \rfloor + \lfloor x+y \rfloor$$

**Case $3$**: $\{x\} >1/2$, $\{y\} >1/2$. Then $$\lfloor 2x \rfloor + \lfloor 2y \rfloor = 2 \lfloor x \rfloor + 2 \lfloor y \rfloor + 2$$
Further, $$\lfloor x+y \rfloor = \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor y \rfloor + 1$$ Hence, we have $$\lfloor 2x \rfloor + \lfloor 2y \rfloor > \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor y \rfloor + \lfloor x+y \rfloor$$