# Proof : $2^{n-1}\mid n!$ if and only if $n$ is a power of $2$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

I want to prove that:

$2^{n-1}\mid n!$ if and only if $n$ is a power of $2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

write out n! and consider how many times each divides by 2 for example 16:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 = 16!
  ^   ^   ^   ^   ^     ^     ^     ^    divisible by 2
      ^       ^         ^           ^    divisible by 2^2
              ^                     ^    divisible by 2^3
                                    ^    divisible by 2^4
```

so there are $16/2 = 8$ numbers there divisible by 2. $16/4 = 4$ numbers there divisible by 2^2. etc.

in total then, there are 16/2 + 16/2^2 + 16/2^3 + 16/2^4.

In general if 2^r is the highest power of 2 dividing n! then $r = \sum_{i=1} [n/2^i]$.

---

To show that $2^{n-1}\mid n!$ we thus want to prove $n-1 = \sum_{i=1} [n/2^i]$ iff $n = 2^k$. ($\Leftarrow$) is immediate from computation. For ($\Rightarrow$) Let $2^{k-1} < n < 2^k$ but then $r < n - 1$ by comparing each term of the summation for $n$ and the one for $2^{k}$.

Comment: I don't understand ($\Rightarrow$)?

Answer (score 9):

*Hint:* It is well-known(?) that the maximal $k$ with $p^k|n!$ is given by
$$k=\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^2}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^3}\right\rfloor+\ldots$$

Comment: this formula is unknown for me? and then?

Comment: This is sometimes known as [De Polignac's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Polignac's_formula) but is also [attributed to Legendre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Number_theory).

Comment: i can not continue,give me more hint.

Comment: Hagen, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141196/highest-power-of-a-prime-p-dividing-n  and many other MSE questions.

Comment: There is also some recent thing for posting fixed, easily searchable quality answers to questions, or parts of questions, that come up over and over and over again. I re-posted my little induction proof there but i do not recall how to find it. Certainly, if some fact is necessary for 100 different questions (this probably qualifies), a post with a few correct proofs seems worthwhile.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula