# Help with counting factors

Tags: number-theory

Can someone help me prove that the product below has $(\large\frac{10^{100}}{6}-\frac{17}{3})$ factors of $7$?

$$\large\prod_{{k}={1}}^{{{10^{100}}}}({4k}+1)$$

Comment: Note that among the terms given, only those of the form $k=7r-2$ contain 7 as a factor. There will be roughly $10^{100}/7$ such terms ($\pm1$). Each of these terms looks like $7(4r-1)$. Removing all these 7, you have a similar product again $\prod (4r-1)$ over $r$ from 1 to $10^{100}/7$ (roughly). These will again have around $10^{100}/49$ terms containing 7 as a factor. Repeating this gives the required value as roughly $\sum {\frac {10^{100}}{7^i}}$, which is close to $10^{100}/6$. Handling all the $\pm 1$ above might give the exact expression you need ($\frac{10^{100}}{6} - \frac{17}{3}$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is a partial answer.

Let $S_n = \displaystyle \prod_{k=1}^n(4k+1)$.

Number of multiples of $7$ in $S_n$ is $\left \lfloor \dfrac{n +2}7 \right\rfloor$

Number of multiples of $7^2$ in $S_n$ is $\left \lfloor \dfrac{n +37}{49} \right\rfloor$

Number of multiples of $7^3$ in $S_n$ is $\left \lfloor \dfrac{n +86}{343} \right\rfloor$

Number of multiples of $7^{2k}$ in $S_n$ is $$\left \lfloor \dfrac{n + 7^{2k} - (7^{2k}-1)/4}{7^{2k}} \right\rfloor = \left \lfloor \dfrac{4n + 3\cdot 7^{2k} + 1}{4 \cdot 7^{2k}} \right\rfloor$$

Number of multiples of $7^{2k+1}$ in $S_n$ is $$\left \lfloor \dfrac{n + 7^{2k+1} - (3 \cdot 7^{2k+1}-1)/4}{7^{2k+1}} \right\rfloor = \left \lfloor \dfrac{4n + 7^{2k+1}+1}{4 \cdot 7^{2k+1}} \right\rfloor$$

Hence, the highest power of $7$ dividing $S_n$ is
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\left \lfloor \dfrac{4n + 7^{2k-1}+1}{4 \cdot 7^{2k-1}} \right\rfloor + \left \lfloor \dfrac{4n + 3\cdot 7^{2k} + 1}{4 \cdot 7^{2k}} \right\rfloor \right)$$

I computed the sum above using [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=summation+floor%28%284%2a10%5E%28100%29+%2B+7%5E%282%2ak-1%29+%2B+1%29%2F4%2F7%5E%282%2ak-1%29%29+%2B+floor%28%284%2a10%5E%28100%29+%2B+3%2a7%5E%282%2ak%29+%2B+1%29%2F4%2F7%5E%282%2ak%29%29+from+k+%3D+1+to+infinity) and it agrees with [$\dfrac{10^{100}}6 - \dfrac{17}3$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2810%5E%28100%29%2F6-17%2F3%29)

Comment: How did you figure out how many multiples of 7 were in the first 1

Comment: Does this reduce the problem to a double summation where the second sigma raises over from n=1 to 10^100

Comment: @Ethan $21 = 4 \times 5 + 1$ is the first number of the form $4k+1$ which gets divided by $7$. Hence, whenever $ k = 5+7 m$ it gets divided by $7$. Similarly for other powers of $7$.

Comment: @Ethan There is no summation over $n$. Just plug in $n=10^{100}$ to get the answer.

Comment: How long did it take you to work this up? Also need you only restrict the sum to log[7,10^100]/2 I think

Comment: @Ethan To write down the sum it took me around $15$ minutes. I did not evaluate the sum for $n=10^{100}$ manually. I used WA to evaluate and compare it. There might be some nice trick to directly get the answer you want without relying on WA.

Comment: I mean how long did it take you to come up with the ideas required to solve the problem

Comment: @Ethan Not needed to restrict till $\log_7(10^{100})/2$ since the remaining terms will anyway be zero due to the floor function.

Comment: @Ethan It took me $15$ minutes to read you question and write down the answer above.

Comment: Not writing, I mean how long did it take you to think up the ideas required to solve the problem

Comment: @Ethan It took me around $3-4$ minutes to figure of how to proceed with the counting.

Comment: @Ethan I new that it should be similar to [finding the highest power of a prime dividing $n!$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141196/highest-power-of-a-prime-p-dividing-n).