# How to find this expression $1000! \mod 3^{300}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation, factorial

How to find this expression  $(1000!\mod 3^{300})$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$3$ goes into $1000!$ at least $300$ times, since it divides $3, 6, 9, \dots, 900$, and hence $3^{300} \mid 1000!$.

Answer (score 2):

Using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141196/highest-power-of-a-prime-p-dividing-n), the highest power of $3$ in $1000!>300$

So, the remainder $=0$

Comment: It's even easier than that: Of the factors in $1000!$, there are 333 multiples of 3. And since $333>300$, …

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\rm\ B^\color{#C00}A \mid (AB)!\, =\, 1\cdot\cdot\: B\,\cdot\cdot\: 2B\,\cdot\cdot\ 3B\,\cdots \color{#C00}AB$
 thus $\:3^{300}\mid 900!\mid 1000!$