# highest value of 'a'

Tags: factorial

I got a question when I started factorials

> Q. If $a^8$ and $8^a$ is completely divisible by $50!$ Then which one of the following is true about 'highest value of a'?
>
> (A)   $10<a<14$
> (B) $14<a<16$
> (C) $16<a<18$
> (D) $18<a<20$

My approach : If we divide $8^a$ by $50!$ then the quotient will not be an integer for any value of *a*.

But the options in this question doesn't say so. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Solution given in the book is as follows:

> Since highest power of $2$ in $50!$ is $47$ hence highest power of $8$ in $50!$ is $[47/3]$ = $15$. Here [] sign denotes greatest integer function.
> If we assume *a* = $15$ then $15^8$ or $3^8$ and $5^8$.
> So we have to check that whether $3^8$ and $5^8$ are divisible by $50!$ or not, Since highest power of $3$ in $50!$ is $22$ and that of $5$ is $12$, hence $a = 15$ will satisfy the condition.

Comment: If $a<20$ (as all the answers state), we can also find primes that divide $50!$ but don't divide $a^8$ (for instance $23, 29, 31...$), thus making $a^8 / 50!$ not an integer as well. Are you sure that the question is not: "If $a^8$ and $8^a$ divide $50!$, then find $a$"?

Comment: @PaoloFranchi i double cross-checked...no mistake in typing the question

Comment: I can only imagine that $a$ is not an integer, but if $a$ is irrational, then there are limited ways in which $a^8$ can be an integer.  Moreover, if somehow $a$ satisfies the divisibility criteria, so will $2a$.  So it seems to me the problem must somehow be garbled.   My suspicion is that $a$ should be an integer and you've reversed the order of division, i.e. that $50!$ should be divisible by both $a^8$ and $8^a$.  Please check.

Comment: See if this helps:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391067/power-of-a-number-in-a-factorial

Comment: @PaoloFranchi  just added the book solution.

Comment: @hardmath just added the book solution.

Comment: @NoChance I did these kind of questions an hour ago. thanks for the reference though.

Comment: So unless you misread after all (another double cross-check wouldn't hurt), the author goofed. Clearly they meant $a^8$ and $8^a$ _divide_ $50!$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Another triple check this time. No mistake by my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you note in the comments, you're right. The author made a typo. This is something that people mess up all the time and is well worth practicing: $a|b$, "a divides b" is not the same as $\frac{a}{b}\in\mathbb{Z}$. Last week a math PhD student got massively confused in a grad CS class after making this very mistake. Always be on your guard about it.