# Find the maximum power of $24$ in $(48!)^2$?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Find the maximum power of $24$ in $(48!)^2$ ?

---

How to approach for such questions ?

Comment: calculate the highest power of $2$ and $3$ that divide $48!$ using polignacs formula.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391067/power-of-a-number-in-a-factorial and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141196/highest-power-of-a-prime-p-dividing-n

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Very helpful !! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$24=\color\red{2^3}\cdot\color\green{3^1}$

---

The multiplicity of $\color\red{2}$ in $48!$ is $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\log_{\color\red{2}}48}\Big\lfloor\frac{48}{\color\red{2}^n}\Big\rfloor=24+12+6+3+1=\color\red{46}$

---

The multiplicity of $\color\green{3}$ in $48!$ is $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\log_{\color\green{3}}48}\Big\lfloor\frac{48}{\color\green{3}^n}\Big\rfloor=16+5+1=\color\green{22}$

---

Therefore:

- The maximum value of $n$ such that $(\color\red{2^3})^n$ divides $48!$ is $\Big\lfloor\frac{\color\red{46}}{\color\red{3}}\Big\rfloor=\color\red{15}$
- The maximum value of $n$ such that $(\color\green{3^1})^n$ divides $48!$ is $\Big\lfloor\frac{\color\green{22}}{\color\green{1}}\Big\rfloor=\color\green{22}$

---

Therefore:

- The maximum value of $n$ such that $(\color\red{2^3})^n$ divides $(48!)^2$ is $\Big\lfloor\frac{\color\red{46}\cdot2}{\color\red{3}}\Big\rfloor=\color\red{30}$
- The maximum value of $n$ such that $(\color\green{3^1})^n$ divides $(48!)^2$ is $\Big\lfloor\frac{\color\green{22}\cdot2}{\color\green{1}}\Big\rfloor=\color\green{44}$

---

Therefore, the maximum value of $n$ such that $24$ divides $(48!)^2$ is $\min(\color\red{30},\color\green{44})=30$.

Comment: Thanks !! Got what I needed !! Just a doubt " Does $48! = 2^{46} . 3^{22}$ " ? Or there are some more numbers which when multiplied to $2^{46} . 3^{22}$ give $48!$ .

Comment: @Garrick: No, of course not. $48!=1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot\ldots\cdot48$.

Comment: @Garrick: No, of course not!!! What other integers are between $1$ and $48$?

Comment: ohh !! Right . My bad. I should be more vigilant . Thanks !!

Comment: @Garrick: You're welcome :)

Comment: If the problem asked about $(50!)^2$ instead of $(48!)^2$: The maximum value of $n$ such that $(2^3)^n$ divides $(50)!$ is $\lfloor\frac{47}3\rfloor=15$ but the maximum value of $n$ such that $(2^3)^n$ divides $(50!)^2$ is $\lfloor\frac{94}3\rfloor=31\ne15\cdot2.$

Comment: @bof: You're right. I should slightly change the answer, since it fits $48$ incidentally... Done...

Comment: @Garrick: Please note the slight modification in the answer (though for the specific case of $(48!)^2$ the bottom line remains the same), due to the comment above made by bof.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**
Use the fact that $24=2^3\cdot3$ and apply [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula) to compute the largest power of $2$ and $3$ in $48!$, i.e.
$$p_2=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \left\lfloor \frac {48}{2^i} \right\rfloor $$
$$p_3=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \left\lfloor \frac {48}{3^i} \right\rfloor$$
For $2$ and $3$ respectively.

Answer (score 3):

Divide $48$ by $2$ repeatedly and add the quotient omitting any remainder,

$48/2=24, 24/2=12, 12/2=6, 6/2=3, 3/2=1$(with remainder as $1$). Therefore adding the quotients,i.e, $24+12+6+3+1=46$ $\Longrightarrow$ there are $46$ $2$s in $48!$ and $92$ $2$s in $(48!)^2$.

Similarly, divide 48 by 3 repeatedly and add the quotients omitting any remainder,

$48/3=16, 16/3=5$ (with remainder as $2$), $5/3=1$ (with remainder as $2$). Adding these quotients gives , $16+5+1=22$ $\Longrightarrow$ There are $22$ $3$s in $48!$ and hence $44$ $3$s in $(48!)^2$.

Now, the number of $24$s ($2^3\times3$)that can be made from $92$ $2$s and $44$ $3$s is $30$.

Comment: how is the number of $24$s that can be made from $46$ $2$s and $22$ $3$s equal to $5$, because a $24$ requires just $3$ $2$s and one $3$, isnt it?

Comment: Thanks Garrick for pointing that out. I edited my answer.

Comment: @Vidyarthi : I am not talking about the number of 2s and 3s in 24 but the "number of 24s" that can be made using 46 twos and 22 threes. Sorry if it's not coming out that clear in the answer.

Comment: you just now edited it. It was actually $15$, but you wrote $5$, which was the cause of all confusion.

Comment: Sorry for that, I hope it's clear now after the edit

Comment: @naveendankal Why multiply by 2 atlast ?

Comment: The question asks for (48!)$^2$ and not 48!.

Comment: The question asks for (48!)2 and not 48!. Say if you are required to find the number of 3s that divide (3!)2. Now, only **one** 3 divides 3! and a total of **two** 3s divide $(3!)^2$ and not $1^2$. Hope that makes it clear.

Comment: You got the right answer but I think you want to multiply by $2$ one step earlier. Supposing there were not $46$ but $47$ $2$s in $48!$ then there would still be $15$ $24$s in $48!$ but $31$ $24$s in $(48!)^2.$

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing that out. I have made the edit in my answer.