# Greatest common divisor power of 6 that divides 73!

Tags: divisibility

Can someone please help me with the following problem?

Compute the largest integer power of 6 that divides 73!.

Comment: since there are more multiples of 2 than 3, it should suffice to find the largest power of 3 that divides $73!$.

Comment: @genisage So how many 3 is in $73!$

Comment: 73/3 rounded down + 73/9 rounded down +73/27 rounded down = 24+8+2=34

Comment: Just as many as there are in $72!$ which is two more than there are in $69!$

Comment: @Pakquebchsoflwty your solution is correct i've checked it with wolframalpha.com. I don't really get why you would take 3, 3^2, and 3^3 though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
73! = 1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot6\cdots\cdots73.
$$
Let's look at how many $3$s from from each of these factors that is a multiple of 3:
$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\text{factor} & \text{3s contributed} \\
3 & 3 \\
6 & 3 \\
9 & 3\cdot3 \\
12 & 3 \\
15 & 3 \\
18 & 3\cdot3 \\
21 & 3 \\
24 & 3 \\
27 & 3\cdot3\cdot3 \\
30 & 3 \\
33 & 3 \\
36 & 3\cdot3 \\
39 & 3 \\
42 & 3 \\
\vdots & \vdots
\end{array}
$$
We get $24$ factors each contibuting at least one $3$.

The ones that are multiples of $9$ contribute at least one more $3$, and there are $8$ of those.

The ones that are multiplies of $27$ contribued at least one more $3$, and there are two of those.

No higher powers of $3$ are involved since we stopped short of $3^4=81$.

So $24+8+2$ is what we're looking for.

(There are more $2$s than $3$s so there are as many $6$s as $3$s.)

Answer (score 1):

You must find the greatest power of $3$ that divides $73!$, since there is much more $2$ in $73!$ rather than $3$. For finding the greatest power of $3$ in $73!$ you can refer to
[Highest power of a prime $p$ dividing $N!$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141196/highest-power-of-a-prime-p-dividing-n)

So it is equal to $\lfloor\frac{73}{3} \rfloor+\lfloor\frac{73}{9} \rfloor+\lfloor\frac{73}{27} \rfloor=24+8+2=34$.

Hence the greatest power of $6$, that divides $73!$ is $34$

Comment: You must have meant there are more $2$s than $3$s. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Be sure to include the actual math in your post.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thank you. I edited it