# Find the greatest positive integer $x$ such that $23^{6+x}$ divides $2000!$

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

I'm currently reading Andreescu and Andrica's *Number Theory: Structures, examples and problems.* Problem 1.1.7 states :
Find the greatest positive integer $x$ such that $23^{6+x}$
divides $2000!$.

The solution given is :

The number $23$ is prime and divides every $23^{rd}$ number. In all, there are
$\lfloor \frac{2000}{23} \rfloor$
= $86$ numbers from $1$ to $2000$ that are divisible by $23$. Among those $86$ numbers, three of them, namely $23, 2 · 23$ and $3 · 23^2$
are divisible by $23^3$. Hence $23^{89} | 2000!$ and $x = 89 − 6 = 83$.

I really don't understand how $23, 2 · 23$ and $3 · 23^2$ are divisible by $23^{3}$ and I hope someone here can shed light on this step in particular, and the overall solution.

EDIT: It appears to have been an error by the authors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Highest power of a prime $p$ dividing $N!$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141196/highest-power-of-a-prime-p-dividing-n)

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: Not a duplicate. This question asks about a specific claim in a specific solution -- giving a _different_ (or general) solution to the problem type would not be an answer to _this_ question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It must be a typo. The list should read "$23^2$, $2\cdot 23^2$ and $3\cdot 23^2$ are divisible by $23^2$".

Comment: Thank you, this makes perfect sense.