# Total number of divisors of factorial of a number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, factorial, prime-factorization

I came across a problem of how to calculate **total number of divisors of factorial** of a number. I know that total number of divisor of a number  $n= p_1^a p_2^b p_3^c $ is $(a+1)*(b+1)*(c+1)$ where $a,b,c$ are the powers of a number $n$ and $1<n<100000$. But how to calculate total number of divisiors for $n!$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just an addition to Ross Millikan's answer:

Remember that the highest power of a prime $p$ dividing $n!$ is given by the procedure:

1. Greatest integer less than or equal to $\frac{n}{p}$
2. Greatest integer less than or equal to $\frac{n}{p^2}$
3. Greatest integer less than or equal to $\frac{n}{p^3}$
4. Repeat until the greatest integer less than or equal to $\frac{n}{p^k}$ is $0$.
5. Add all of your numbers up!

**Example:** Power of $3$ in the factorization of $100!$:

1. Greatest integer less than or equal to $\frac{100}{3}$ is $33$
2. Greatest integer less than or equal to $\frac{100}{3^2}$ is $11$
3. Greatest integer less than or equal to $\frac{100}{3^3}$ is $3$
4. Greatest integer less than or equal to $\frac{100}{3^4}$ is $1$
5. Greatest integer less than or equal to all the fractions after this is zero: $\frac{100}{3^5} > \frac{100}{3^6} > \cdots$
6. Add: $33 + 11 + 3 + 1 = 48$.

I would assume you would do this for every prime under $n$ and use the formula in Ross's answer.

Comment: I had searched the site for that and couldn't find it.  Then I tried Google with "power of prime dividing factorial" and it came up with one of our pages, which I now link to.

Comment: I see it now. I guess I'll leave my answer here, though, just for convenience.

Comment: Less than or equal to.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 5):

You have to assess the powers of all the primes less than $n$ in $n!$ and use  the formula you cite.  For example, $8!=40320=2^7\cdot3^2\cdot 5 \cdot 7$, so it has $(7+1)(2+1)(1+1)(1+1)=96$ factors.  The way to calculate the power of the primes is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141196/highest-power-of-a-prime-p-dividing-n)