# Highest power of a prime in the product of consecutive factorials

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$y$ and $n$ are positive integers.

$1!\times2!\times3!\times...\times26! = y\times13^n$

$n$ is equals ?

($n$ is above)

Comment: Do you mean $y*13^n$ with positive integers $y$ and $n$?

Comment: yes exactly ...

Comment: Write down the prime factorisation of the whole number, and then see how many $13$'s you've got. (Note that it's semi-factorised already, so it shouldn't be too hard.)

Comment: There are multiple answers of course, with $1\leq n\leq 15$.  Are you looking for a specific one?  Maybe the one with the largest $n$?

Comment: yes the largest n

Comment: answers are 11 12 13 14 15

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141196/highest-power-of-a-prime-p-dividing-n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In $x!$, where $ 13 \le x \le 25$ there is only one 13 in each number: this gives $25-13+1 = 13$ of the nmber Thirteen. Note that when $x=26$, the number has 2 "Thirteens" so the total answer is $n = 15$

Perhaps a more interesting or instructive question would be to count the number of zeroes at the end of the your number.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're looking for the largest $n$.

Hint: Since $13$ is prime, $1!$, $2!$, ..., $12!$ do not contain a factor of $13$. Each of $13!$, $14!$, ..., $25!$ have exactly one factor of $13$, and $26!$ has two factors of $13$ (one coming from $13$ and the other from $26=2*13$)... Add those together and that should be your answer.