# What is the Max value of n when 185! is divided by (189^n) will give an Integer Value?

Tags: number-theory

> What is the Max value of n when $185!$ is divided by $(189^n)$ will give an Integer Value?

Options are

a) $91$ 
b) $30$ 
c) $36$
d) $24$

MyApproach:

$189$=$3^3$ . $7$

When $185$/$3$=$61$

$61$/$3$=$20$

$20$/$3$=$6$

$6$/$3$=$2$

Its Remainder Sum=$89$

$185$/$7$=$26$

$26$/$7$=$3$

Its Remainder Sum=$29$

So,3^89 . $7$^$29$

$27$^$29$ . $7$^$29$

I am getting $29$ as the final Ans.

Required Ans is 30
Why i am getting the Ans wrong?
Also,

Is there any better approach i can solve this problem.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your approach. Nor with the result. Basically you were correctlt applying [this recipe](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/141196/11619). Adding the link in case some future reader needs an explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well,

```
Prelude> let m = product [1 .. 185] :: Integer
Prelude> m `mod` (189^29)
0
Prelude> m `mod` (189^30)
37470960172551150153411831285317353601062526805310229978097429296724
```

it's not you who is wrong. Your result is correct, the required answer is incorrect.

> Is there any better approach I can solve this problem?

Not really, counting the (relevant) prime powers dividing the factorial is the best method generally.

Comment: I have not understood what u meant.Its sarcastic.Please explain in detail

Comment: It wasn't meant sarcastically. You did everything right, the expected answer is wrong.

Comment: okay Yes u showed the way How to check your Ans. and yes the expected the Ans is Wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is right. Here is how I do it:

As $189=3^3\cdot 7$, $\;185!$ is divisible by $189^n=3^{3n}\cdot7^n$ if and only if
$$v_3(185!)\ge 3n\enspace\text{and}\enspace v_7(185!)\ge n$$
(for a prime number $p$, $v_p(n)$ denotes the $p$-adic valuation of $p$ in $n$, i.e. the exponent of $p$ in the decomposition of $n$ into its prime factors)

We can use *Legendre's formula* to find the valuations of a factorial:
$$v_p(n!)=\biggl\lfloor\frac np\biggr\rfloor+\biggl\lfloor\frac n{p^2}\biggr\rfloor+\biggl\lfloor\frac n{p^3}\biggr\rfloor+\dotsm$$
(this sum is actually finite). In the present case we obtain:
$$v_3(185)=61+20+6+2=89,\quad v_7(185)=26+3=29,$$
hence we must have $\;3n\le 89$ and $n\le 29$. The greatest $n$ that satisfies both conditions is indeed $29$.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be analize of a different approach. If we analize $185!$ taking advantage that $7$ is prime, we see that

$$
185!=n(7*14*21*28*35*42*49*56*63*70*77*84*\ldots*175*182). 
$$
The number of factors that contains $7$ are $[185/7]=26$. But, there others factors that altes our result such that
$$
49,98,147.
$$
In summary, there existe $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ co-prime with $7$ such that
$$
185!=m*7^{26+1+1+1}=7^{29}m.
$$ 
If $189^n$ divides $185!$ is neccesary that $7^n$ divides $185!$. For our last result $n\leq 29$. So if $189^n$ divides $185!$, then $n\leq 29$.

If we analize for $3$ we have:

$[185/3]=61$.

$[185/9]=20$.

$[185/27]=6$.

So, we have that $185!=3^{61+20+6}r=3^{87}r=27^{29}r$. With $r$ does not contain $3$. For all of this we have

$$
185!=27^{29}7^{29}k=189^{29}k,
$$
where $k$ doesn't contain $189$. This means that the max $n$ such that $189^n$ divides $185!$ is 29.

The options are wrong.

Comment: [The correct answer is *not* 24, but 29.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=185%21+mod+189%5E29)