# Show that $p^{n-1}$ does not divide $k!$, with $p$ an odd prime, $n>1$ and $0<k<n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, factorial

I am trying to prove this claim, which seems true to me, in the process of trying to prove that $p^{n-1}$ divides ${p^{n-1} \choose k}$. Besides the conditions stated in the title, I have already proven that $p^{n-1}$ is strictly larger than $k$.

This has been my final obstacle. It is simple enough with just $p$, but the fact that $p^{n-1}$ is not prime for $n>2$ has made it difficult for me. I'd appreciate any insight.

Comment: Use curly braces for exponents containing more than one symbol. For instance, while `p^(n-1)` looks bad, `p^{n-1}` becomes $p^{n-1}$.

Comment: Thank you to everyone for the help! All answers have been helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [Fundamental Theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) :

> Every natural number greater that $1$ can be written as a product of prime numbers in a **unique** way (up to order).

In particular, when writing
$$k!=1\cdot 2\cdots k,$$
if $p^{n-1}|k!$, then the product must contain at least $n-1$ factor $p$.

Now the number of times $p$ appears in $k!$ can be computed by the following formula :
$$\left\lfloor \frac{k}{p}\right \rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{k}{p^2}\right\rfloor +\dots +\left\lfloor \frac{k}{p^{n-2}}\right\rfloor .$$

For a justification of this, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141196/highest-power-of-a-prime-p-dividing-n) (and notice that I can end the sum at $\left\lfloor \frac{k}{p^{n-2}}\right\rfloor$ because $k<p^{n-1}$).

Thus the number of factor $p$ in $k!$ is less than
$$\frac{k}{p}+\dots +\frac{k}{p^{n-2}}=\frac{k}{p}\left(1+\dots \frac{1}{p^{n-3}}\right) =\frac{k}{p}\cdot \dfrac{1-\frac{1}{p^{n-2}}}{1-\frac{1}{p}}\leq \frac{k}{p-1}\leq \frac{k}{2}<k\leq n-1.$$

Comment: Thank you very much. It may be obvious, but would you mind explaining why the fact that p is prime implies this? Is there a general divisibility fact that you're using?

Comment: @CuriousKid Non-primes divide factorials more times than primes do, relative to their size. For instance, given some $n$, $35$ divides $n!$ as many times as $7$ does,  while $31$ and $37$ divides $n!$ a lot fewer times. Specifically, $35!$ is divisible by $35^5$, but only $31^1$ and not at all by $37$. This can, of course, be made more strict and formal, but that's the idea.

Comment: @Arnaud I understand that it must contain at least n-1 factors of p, but I don't understand how this implies your statement in italics.

Comment: @CuriousKid7 It didn't, the question was more complicated than I thought, but it's corrected now.

Answer (score 2):

The highest multiplicity with which $p$ divides $k!$ is (this sum is of course only formally infinite) 
$$\sum_{j\ge 1} \left\lfloor\frac{k}{p^j} \right\rfloor.$$
To see this note that there are $\lfloor\frac{k}{p} \rfloor$ multiples of $p$ less than or equal to $k$, and $\lfloor\frac{k}{p^2} \rfloor$ multiples of $p^2$ etc. Note that the count is good as multiples of $p$ are counted once, while multiples of $p^2$ are counted twice etc.

Thus you are left with showing that 
$$\sum_{j\ge 1} \left \lfloor\frac{k}{p^j}\right \rfloor  < k$$
Now $\sum_{j\ge 1} \left \lfloor\frac{k}{p^j}\right \rfloor \le \sum_{j\ge 1} \frac{k}{p^j} = k\sum_{j\ge 1} \frac{1}{p^j} = k \frac{1/p}{1-1/p}= k \frac{1}{p-1},$
which is at most $k/2$  for $p$ odd prime, and thus less than $k$.

Answer (score 1):

One can try the following approach, which I use to prove the first Sylow theorem: let us write the binomial coefficient as

$$\binom{p^{n-1}}{k}=\frac{p^{n-1}(p^{n-1}-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot\overbrace{(p^{n-1}-(p^{n-1}-k-1))}^{=k+1}}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot\ldots\cdots (p^{n-1}-k)}$$

Now, we have

Lemma: for some power $\;0\le r\le n-1\;$ of $\;p\;$ and for all $\;0\le j\le k\;$, we have that $\;p^r\,\mid (p^n-j)\iff p^r\,\mid\,j\;$

Proof: Almost trivial. Try it.

Thus, we get that there's cancelation of $\;p^r\;$ every time this power of $\;p\;$ divides some factor in the numerator...or in the denominator, of course, and thus $\;p^{n-1}\;$ remains uncancelled. The problem's solved once one remembers any binomial coefficient is *always* an integer.