# Trouble understanding Legendre's formula and inductive proof of it

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, induction, prime-factorization

The part I'm having trouble with specifically is how/why does the sum $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^i}\right\rfloor$$ give the greatest power of $p$ for which $n!$ is divisible. How is counting the multiples of $p$, $p^2$, $p^3$,... in $n$ related to $n!$ in such a way that when you sum up all of those you get the greatest power of $p$ that divides $n!$.

Also how would an inductive proof of the Legendre's formula look like? I've tried proving it specifically for $p=2$ and I took my IH to be $$v_2(n!)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2^i}\right\rfloor$$ but I can't seem to extend this for $n+1$.

Comment: There is an induction proof provided here, but I can't quite understand what is the IH and how does this prove the validity of the statement for $n+1$ ?

Comment: Did you take a look at the accepted answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141196/highest-power-of-a-prime-p-dividing-n?noredirect=1&lq=1 ?

Comment: @StubbornAtom I did though I still couldn't really understand the connection. I guess that my confusion arises from not understanding how does $$\left \lfloor\frac{N}{p^i}\right\rfloor$$ counts terms that are multiples of p **less** than $N$, and how do they contribute to $N!$ rather than to $N$ itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The induction in the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2024004/65332) (which you are presumably referring to, seeing your comment on it) is different than you would expect. Normally you would show that the formula holds for $1$ (or some other anchor) and then show that $φ(n+1)$ follows from $φ(n)$, thus creating a chain of inductions like

```
1 ⇒ 2 ⇒ 3 ⇒ 4 ⇒ 5 ⇒ ...
```

The validity of $φ(1)$ thus extends to any $n$.

In the case of the Legendre formula this is different: you prove $φ(n)$ using $φ(\lfloor n/2\rfloor)$ instead of using $φ(n-1)$. Or you can say that from the hypothesis of $φ(m)$ you derive the validity of $φ(2m)$ and also $φ(2m+1)$ because that has the same result of $\lfloor\circ/2\rfloor$.

So the pattern looks more like

```
            4
      2 ⇒ { 5
1 ⇒ {
      3 ⇒ { 6
            7 etc.
```

and covers all $n$ in a different, yet fully justified, fashion.

It's analogous with higher primes.

Comment: So cool. I'm guessing that this is possible because of nature of the floor function since in its case $\phi(2rn)$=$\phi(2rn+1)$ ?

Comment: Almost: I meant to say that (yes, because the nature of the floor function) $\lfloor(2m)/2\rfloor = \lfloor(2m+1)/2\rfloor$ so $\phi(2m)$ and $\phi(2m+1)$ (different) follow both from the same IH.

Comment: Btw. I used $m$ as in M, there's no need to write it as a product of R N. I suppose it just looked the same in lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $$\nu_p((n-1)!)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\left\lfloor \frac {n-1}{p^i}\right\rfloor.$$
If $n=p^ku$ with $p\nmid u$ and $k\ge 0$ then we have
$ \left\lfloor \frac {n}{p^i}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor \frac {n-1}{p^i}\right\rfloor+1$
for $k\ge i$ and 
$ \left\lfloor \frac {n}{p^i}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor \frac {n-1}{p^i}\right\rfloor$
for $k< i$, hence 
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty\left\lfloor \frac {n}{p^i}\right\rfloor =\sum_{i=1}^\infty\left\lfloor \frac {n-1}{p^i}\right\rfloor+\sum_{i=1}^k1=\nu_p((n-1)!)+k=\nu_p((n-1)!)+\nu_p(n)=\nu_p(n!)$$