# Simple factorial problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factorial

How do I solve the following?

> $$\dfrac{76!}{76!-75!}$$

Comment: $76! - 75! = 76(75!)-75! = 75!(76-1) = 75(75!)$ and so you have $$\frac{76(75!)}{75(75!)}$$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highest power of a prime $p$ dividing $N!$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141196/highest-power-of-a-prime-p-dividing-n)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$76! = 76\cdot 75!$$

$$\frac{76!}{76!-75!} = \frac{75!\cdot 76}{75!(76-1)} = \frac{76}{75}
$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT

76! = 76*75! Plug that in and see what you get

Answer (score 1):

Note that $76!=76*75!$ and that $76!-75!=75!(76-1)$, so then we see that $\frac{76!}{76!-75!}=\frac{76*75!}{75!(76-1)}=\frac{76}{75}$