# How do I show there is always an integer $k>1$ and $k<n$ for which :$\displaystyle n! \bmod {n}^{k}\neq 0$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, congruences

Really i'm interesting to know if there is any Theorem  show that always there  exist an integer $k>1$  for which :$\displaystyle n! \bmod {n}^{k}\neq 0$?
for example we take [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table+of+%5B10!+mod10%5Ek%5D+,++k%3D2+to+100) as example : $n=10 $ with $k=2$ to $100$, we see that from $k=3$ to $100$  :$\displaystyle 10! \bmod {10}^{k}\neq 0$.

**My modest question is**: Is there any theorem or any known result show that always there  exist an integer $k>1$ with  $k<n$  for which :$\displaystyle n! \bmod {n}^{k}\neq 0$?.

Thank you for any help

Comment: If $k>n$ then $n^k>n!$, hence $n!\mod n^k = n!$.

Comment: pleas i avoid this case  it's a trivial i don't mean the trivial case

Comment: Then specify what you really mean.

Comment: Now $n^{n-1}$ is still bigger than $n!$ if $n>2$.

Comment: Example : 6 ! mod 6^3 neq 0

Comment: Please give some context as to why this question has become so important to you.  If we know what you're hoping to prove, ultimately, we can better answer this question.  Why do you need an answer to your question?

Comment: This question is important to me  i w'd like to know numbers are not divisble by n! and in the same time to check the factorisation of n!-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n! \equiv 0 \pmod {n^k}$, then $n^k \mid n!$. To find a small $k$ such that $n^k \nmid n!$, we consider the largest prime $p$ dividing $n$. If $p^k \nmid n!$, then clearly $n^k \nmid n!$.

Fortunately, [we know exactly how many times $p$ divides $n!$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/141196/9754).

So choosing any $k$ satisfying
$$ k > \sum_{j \geq 1} \left \lfloor \frac{n}{p^j} \right \rfloor$$

will suffice. Note that
$$ \sum_{j \geq 1} \left \lfloor \frac{n}{p^j} \right \rfloor \leq \sum_{j \geq 1} \frac{n}{p^j} = \frac{n}{p} \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{p}} = \frac{n}{p-1},$$
which is always less than $n$ as long as $n$ has a prime factor larger than $2$.

The case when $n = 2^m$ for some $m$ is a bit more annoying and should be handled separately. But having only one prime to worry about simplifies the analysis.