# Induction involving primes

Tags: prime-numbers, induction

Use induction to prove that for every positive integer $n$, when we factor the product $$(n+1)(n+2)...(2n-1)2n$$ into primes, there are exactly $n$ copies of the prime $2$.

I do not really understand what the question is asking.

Comment: @AdamHughes they are asking for $$  \nu_2 ((2n)!) -  \nu_2 (n!) $$ which follows from Legendre's rule https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre's_formula

Comment: @WillJagy ah, OK, I can see it now. Thanks for that!

Comment: @AdamHughes, I like this question. I wrote a proof of Legendre's formula strictly using induction in an answer on this site. I seem not to have saved the link. Good exercise, though not difficult.

Comment: @WillJagy yeah, it's a cute exercise, I agree. I always go the counting route, but then that's my analytic background showing through, I like the idea of an inductive proof a lot now that this question notes that the approach is quite straight-forwardly viable. :)

Comment: @AdamHughes found my early version http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141196/highest-power-of-a-prime-p-dividing-n/228351#228351

Comment: Thanks for the tag and the link @WillJagy !

Answer (score 3):

Let $P_n$ be your number.  We want to show that $2^n\,||\,P_n$.  That is, we want to show that $2^n$ divides $P_n$ but $2^{n+1}$ does not.  It is easy to check that this is true if $n=1$ ($P_1=2$) or if $n=2$ (as we have $P_2=3\times 4 = 12$).

Let us assume that we have settled the point for $P_n$. Thus we can write  $P_n=2^nM$ for some odd $M$.  Inductively, we now want to address the issue for $P_{n+1}$.

Specifically, we want to show that $2^{n+1}\,||\,P_{n+1}$.  Of course we have $$P_{n+1}=\frac {(2n+1)(2n+2)}{n+1}P_n=2(2n+1)P_n=2(2n+1)\times 2^nM=2^{n+1}(2n+1)M$$

As $(2n+1)M$ is odd, we see that we are done.

Comment: note that Legendre's formula, for any fixed prime, can be proved by induction. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre's_formula  And this problem is a consequence of Legendre's formula for prime $2$

Comment: @WillJagy  Thanks.  I don't tend to think of Legendre's formula as an inductive statement...interesting!