# Formulate xor matrix

Tags: optimization, problem-solving

Recently I was trying some problems related to XOR operation, And I found this problem somewhere(Can't find out now), there is a function defined like this,

$f(i,j)$ = $1$ if i=$0$ or j = $0$

$f(i,j)$ = $f(i-1,j)$  $XOR$  $f(i,j-1)$ else

And we have to calculate $f(i,j)$ for really big numbers which can not be solved by just iteration. Can consider $i,j$ <= $10^{15}$

**My Effort:**

I was trying to observe something in terms of patterns, that I formed after printing matrix by just iterating over $i$ and $j$, for $20*20$ matrix. I found that it's forming inverted triangles in kind of nested form and of size $2^n-1$, but I still don't know how could I formulate or find a better way to calculate this function in lesser complexity than $O(i*j)$. I am expecting some logarithmic complexity which I am assuming is possible because of above patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $a\mathbin{\sf xor}b = a+b \bmod 2$ when $a,b\in\{0,1\}$. So your matrix is [Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_triangle) modulo 2:
$$ f(i,j) = \binom{i+j}{i} \bmod 2 $$

So in order to calculate it, you just need to be able to find out whether $\binom{m}{n} = \frac{m!}{(m-n)!n!} $ is even or odd. You can do that by computing how many factors of $2$ there are in each of the factorials and checking if there are as many in the denominator as in the numerator.

For counting factors of $2$ in a factorial, see [Highest power of a prime $p$ dividing $n!$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141196/highest-power-of-a-prime-p-dividing-n).

Comment: And finding out the number of factors of 2 (or any number) in a factorial (and consequently the binomial coefficient) can be done in logarithmical time as OP speculates and is a fun technique worth looking into

Comment: Thanks guys.. Btw.. How did you see it's correlation with Pascal Triangle?? and how did you find $f(i,j)$ from that..??

Comment: @KautsyaKanu: As for how I _noticed_, I don't think I have an explanation other than it comes with experience from thinking about related problems.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ok, Thank you for help.. :)

Comment: @HenningMakholm I was thinking to solve this problem further... Can you guide me how can I write $i^{th}$ row of this matrix(formed from $f(i,j)$) with help of previous rows in some logarithmic approach? Like how we represent a number in any base.. 5 = 1*$2^2$ + 0*$2^1$ + 1*$2^0$ , I read some articles on Pascal's binary matrix but none help for this one..