# An intuitive proof of the conventional technique to find the greatest exponent of a prime factor $p$ in $n!$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Usually, it is done like this: If $[t]$ denotes the greatest integer less than or equal to $t$, then

$$ \text{the exponent of $p$ in $n!$} = \bigg[\frac{n}{p}\bigg] + \bigg[\frac{n}{p^2}\bigg] + \bigg[\frac{n}{p^3}\bigg] + \cdots $$

and it does give the answer, but, it is totally non-intuitive and i can't use it comfortably enough!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I edited your question to a more readable form. Please take a moment to give a read on [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: MathJax hint:  rather than square brackets for the floor function we use \lfloor and \rfloor.  You can prefix them with \left and \right as well.

Comment: Why isnt your answer intuitive enough? Imagine lining up all the integers from 1 to n. Every p elements are divisible by p at least once. Count them. Every p$^{2}$  elements are divisible by p at least once more. Count them. Etc...

Comment: I wrote a proof using induction years ago, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141196/highest-power-of-a-prime-p-dividing-n/228351#228351

Comment: David Diaz...... .So basically, the floor function literally "counts" the factors???

Answer (score 3):

The $\left\lfloor \frac np \right\rfloor$ counts one factor of $p$ from every multiple of $p$.  The $\left\lfloor \frac n{p^2} \right\rfloor$ counts one additional factor of $p$ from every multiple of $p^2$ and so on.  As an example, take $p=5, n=679$.  There are $\left\lfloor \frac {679}5 \right\rfloor=135$ multiples of $5$, starting with $5$ and ending with $675=5\cdot 135$.  The multiples of $25$ have another factor of $5$ and there are $\left\lfloor \frac {679}{25} \right\rfloor=27$ of them.  The multiples of $5^3=125$ have another factor of $5$ and the one multiple of $5^4=625$ has yet one more.

Answer (score 1):

It is easily understood in terms of double counting: if $\operatorname{ord}_p m$ denotes the exponent of the factor $p$ in $m$ and

$$ \mathbf{1}_{\{\cdots\}} = \begin{cases}
1, & \text{if $\cdots$ is true} \\
0, & \text{if $\cdots$ is false}
\end{cases} $$

denotes the indicator function for the statement $\cdots$, then

$$ \operatorname{ord}_p (n!)
= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \operatorname{ord}_p k
= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sum_{l=1}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}_{\{p^l \mid k\}}
= \sum_{l=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \mathbf{1}_{\{p^l \mid k\}}
= \sum_{l=1}^{\infty} \bigg\lfloor \frac{n}{p^l} \bigg\rfloor. \tag{1}$$

The following figure demonstrates the case $n = 65$ with $p=2$.

$\hspace{4em}$[image: figure 1: bins]

Here, the presence of a black bead at $(k, l)$ means that $p^l$ divides $k$. So

- The number of beads at $k$ represents the highest power of $p$ that divides $k$, hence is $\operatorname{ord}_p k$.
- The number of beads at height $l$ represents the total number of integers $\leq n$ which are divisible by $p^l$, i.e., the number of multiples of $p^l$ in $\{1, \cdots, n\}$. This is exactly $\lfloor n/p^l \rfloor$.

Then the LHS of $\text{(1)}$ counts the total number of beans from left to right, while the RHS of $\text{(1)}$ counts the total number of beans from bottom to top.