# For how many integers $n$ is $\frac{(n^3)!}{(n!)^{n^2-1}((n^2+1)!-(n^2)!)}$ an integer?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, factorial

I'm asked to find the number of integers $n$ from 1 to 100, inclusive, such that $$\frac{(n^3)!}{(n!)^{n^2-1}((n^2+1)!-(n^2)!)}$$ is an integer. This problem was from our test and was a bonus problem created by my crazy math teacher. How do I even begin? This expression looks too daunting for me to even attempt, and I can't see any easy simplifications. The answer says $\boxed{74}$ integers. How do I begin?
EDIT: SORRY: The answer is $\boxed{74}$, not 84. My bad! Typo

Comment: I see one start but it's too basic. use the -1 exponent to more a term to the numerator.

Comment: What is $(a+1)!-a!$ for any integer a? =)

Comment: I think that it is $a\cdot a!$. How does that help simplify this?

Comment: @Jithinash Was the bonus problem expected to be solved during class, or at home?  If at home, is it sufficient to write a computer program to empirically check each value of $n$, or are you required to **mathematically derive** an answer?  See next comment.

Comment: @Jithinash  For what its worth, I would define $v_p(k)$ to equal the largest exponent $\alpha$ such that $p^{\alpha}$ divides $k$.  It is immediately obvious that for any prime $p$ greater than $n$, $v_p$(the numerator) is $\geq v_p$(the denominator).  This means you have to look for $n$ and prime $p \leq n$ such that $v_p$(the numerator) is $\lt v_p$(the denominator).  One place to start is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141196/highest-power-of-a-prime-p-dividing-n.  Of course, if computer programming is permitted, then math analysis becomes moot.

Comment: @Jithinash I should warn you; I used my previous comment as a guide and didn't find any elegant manipulation that would generate an answer.

Comment: @user2661923 you may not be such an analytic programmer then... you can use tons of logic ( relsted to combinatorics, etc of code design)  necessary conditions,(to weed out those thst can't work) etc.

Comment: I just checked with Mathematica, and it seems there are $74$ values of $n$ for which the quantity is an integer. Perhaps someone made a typo? Code: `f[n_] := Factorial[n^3]/(Factorial[n]^(n^2 - 1)*Factorial[n^2]*n^2);Length[Select[Range[100],IntegerQ[f[#]]&]]`

Comment: @Jithinash based on the responses on this page, I speculate that the original problem has a typo (perhaps mistake of teacher) for 2 reasons: (1) the teacher gave a specific answer (i.e. 84) which has been proven wrong. (2) no one has given a **complete algebraic-manipulation-based** analysis.  Assuming that your class is teaching math rather than computer programming, the problem **seems pointless** if it doesn't yield to (reasonably straightforward) algebraic manipulation.

Answer (score 3):

I started out writing this answer assuming that your teacher's result was correct. I have left this reasoning in the answer since it might be of interest to you as to how you might tackle problems of this sort. However, it would have been easier to only consider $n$ prime to demonstrate that the result of $84$ is incorrect.

> Preliminary Result 1  Let $a,b,t$ be integers such that $n=at+b,t>b\ge0$. Then $$\left\lfloor \frac{n^3}{t}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor \frac{n^2}{t}\right\rfloor-(n^2-1)\left\lfloor \frac{n}{t}\right\rfloor=a+ab(b-1)+an(b-1)+\left\lfloor \frac{b^3}{t}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor \frac{b^2}{t}\right\rfloor.$$

**Proof**

The result follows immediately upon substituting $n^2=(an+ab)t+b^2$ and $n^3=(an^2+abn+ab^2)t+b^3.$

Note that this expression is positive if $b>0$.

> Preliminary Result 2
>   For any prime $p$ the power of $p$ dividing the numerator and denominator of the given expression are, respectively, as follows.
>   $$\left\lfloor \frac{n^3}{p}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor \frac{n^3}{p^2}\right\rfloor+...$$
>   $$\left\lfloor \frac{n^2}{p}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor \frac{n^2}{p^2}\right\rfloor+...+(n^2-1)\left(\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^2}\right\rfloor+...\right)+v_p(n^2)$$

**Proof**

This is an application of the standard result for prime divisors of $n!$

> When is the given expression an integer?

Suppose it is not an integer. Then there must be a prime $p$ for which the power of $p$ dividing the numerator is less than that dividing the denominator. Applying the two preliminary results and with $t=p,p^2,p^3,...$, we see that this can only occur for a prime divisor $p$ of $n$.

However, as a test of your teacher's result let us consider just the case $n=p$. Applying Preliminary Result 2 we obtain $p^2+p+1$ for the power of $p$ dividing the numerator and  $p^2+p+2$ for the power of $p$ dividing the denominator. So the expression is not an integer for any of the $25$ primes less than $100$.

Answer (score 0):

It can done as distribution of $n^3$ number of distinct objects into $n^2$ number of identical groups such that each group get exactly $n$ objects and other factor $\frac{(n-1)!}{n}$ is not an integer if $n$ is a prime number. In first 100 natural number there are 25 numbers.
For detailed solution you can check here https://www.mathsdiscussion.com/discussion-forum/topic/distribution-of-distinct-objects-2/?part=1#postid-100

Comment: Isn't that distribution just $\left(n^3\right)!/\left(n!\right)^{n^2}$? How do we interpret the division by $\left(n^2\right)!$?

Comment: I will suggest you just go through this article on distribution of distinct objects into distinct groups and identical groups https://www.mathsdiscussion.com/permutation-and-combination/.      You will find more such question in that and can check in discussion forum also.and can listen to podcast for better clarity links are in the article itself.

Comment: Ok, what if the other factor is not an integer? Why do we know the expression is non-integer? Non-integer $\times$ integer might be an integer.

Comment: This is good progress to a solution, but is not complete. To show that the expression is not an integer when $n$ is prime, it is not enough to say it is of the form $\text{integer}\times\text{rational}$. You need to count the number of factors of $p$ in the numerator and denominator. $\tag*{}$To show it _is_ an integer when $n$ is not prime, you need to show $(n-1)!/n$ is an integer when $n$ is composite. This takes works, and is not always true; in fact, there is one composite $n\in [1,100]$ for which the expression is not an integer.