# How to find repeated factors in a number without factorising

Tags: prime-factorization

If I have any number, for example, $120$

The prime factorisation of $120$ being:
$$2 × 2 × 2 × 3 × 5$$

Then, is there an easy way that I can find out that the number $120$ has a repeated factor (i.e., the number $2$ occurs three times in the prime factorization of $120$), without factorizing the number $120$?

Comment: Did you choose $120$ because you were looking for the highest power of $2$ in $5!$ ?

Comment: @SathvikAcharya i just chose 120 because it had a repeated prime factor

Comment: The reason I asked about your choice was [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141196/highest-power-of-a-prime-p-dividing-n)

Comment: For the general case, see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/16098) over on MO. TL;DR, it doesn't seem to be easy.

Comment: From the wiki on square-free integers: "In particular, there is no known polynomial-time algorithm for computing the square-free part of an integer, *or even for determining whether an integer is square-free*."

Comment: A number $abcd$ where variables are digits will have two or more $2$s in the factorization if $cd$ is a multiple of $4$. There will be two or more $3$s if $a+b+c+d$ is a multiple of $9$.

Comment: There is no better way , apart from special cases like powers of $2$ or $5$ for which we only need the last digits , but repeated division is anyway a cheap operation.