# $n \in \mathbb{N},$ if $2^a|n!$, the largest $\alpha=\left[\frac{n}{2}\right]+\left[\frac{n}{4}\right]+\cdots+\left[\frac{n}{2^{2021}}\right]+\cdots$,

Tags: number-theory

Sorry that I can't put the entire question in the title. It should be:

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that the largest integer $\alpha$ with the property that $2^{\alpha}$ divides $n !$ is equal to
$$
\alpha=\left[\frac{n}{2}\right]+\left[\frac{n}{4}\right]+\left[\frac{n}{8}\right]+\cdots+\left[\frac{n}{2^{2021}}\right]+\cdots
$$
where $[x]$ always represents the largest integer less than or equal to the real number $x$.

Is it saying that if $n! = 2^a \cdot k$, for some integer $k$, then the largest
$$
\alpha=\left[\frac{n}{2}\right]+\left[\frac{n}{4}\right]+\left[\frac{n}{8}\right]+\cdots+\left[\frac{n}{2^{2021}}\right]+\cdots{}?
$$

I am trying to prove is by induction, then I got the following:
\begin{align*}
(n+1)! &= 2^a \cdot k \cdot (n+1) = 2^{a+\log_2 (n+1)} \cdot k \\
&\Longrightarrow \; a + \log_2 (n+1) = \left[\frac{n+1}{2}\right]+\left[\frac{n+1}{4}\right]+\left[\frac{n+1}{8}\right]+\cdots+\left[\frac{n+1}{2^{2021}}\right]+\cdots
\end{align*}

Then I subtract the two equations and got:
\begin{align*}
\log_2 (n+1) 
={} &\left( \left[\frac{n+1}{2}\right] - \left[\frac{n}{2}\right] \right) 
+ \left( \left[\frac{n+1}{4}\right] - \left[\frac{n}{4}\right] \right) 
+ \left( \left[\frac{n+1}{8}\right] - \left[\frac{n}{8}\right] \right) \\
&{}+ \cdots + \left( \left[\frac{n+1}{2^{2021}}\right] 
- \left[\frac{n}{2^{2021}}\right] \right) +\cdots{}
\end{align*}

And I stuck at here, I understand for each term, the difference is either $1$ or $0$, but what can I do for the next step? Really hope to get some hints/help!! Thank you!

Comment: Your statement represents the special case of [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula) with $p = 2$.  The referenced wikipedia article contains a *proof* (of sorts) for the general formula.  The proof given is really just an *appeal to intuition*.  My "Elementary Number Theory" (Uspensky and Heaslett) gave the same intuitive proof.

Comment: Re previous comment, I have never seen anyone attempt to prove the formula by induction, going from $(n!)$ to $(n+1)!$.

Comment: For what it's worth, one way of stretching your intuition to accommodate the corresponding proof is to manually calculate $v_5(100!) = 24$, and then calculate $$\left\lfloor \frac{100}{5}\right\rfloor ~+~ \left\lfloor \frac{100}{25}\right\rfloor.$$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141196/highest-power-of-a-prime-p-dividing-n/228351#228351  induction

Comment: It says in the tag description for [tag:solution-verification] that "This should not be the only tag for a question".

Comment: There's no need to put the entire question in the title