# Prove that $\frac{100!}{50!\cdot2^{50}} \in \Bbb{Z}$

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to prove that :

$$\frac{100!}{50!\cdot2^{50}}$$

is an integer .

For the moment I did the following :

$$\frac{100!}{50!\cdot2^{50}} = \frac{51 \cdot 52 \cdots 99 \cdot 100}{2^{50}}$$

But it still doesn't quite work out .

Hints anyone ?

Thanks

Comment: Think the numbers of multiple of 2, multiple of 4, multiple of 8, ..., etc in {51, 52, ..., 99, 100}.

Comment: Using \displaystyle in the title is depreciated.

Comment: If you make it dependent on $n$, then this is called a [double factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial).

Answer (score 122, accepted):

$$ \frac{(2n)!}{n! 2^{n}} = \frac{\prod\limits_{k=1}^{2n} k}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n} (2k)} = \prod_{k=1}^{n} (2k-1) \in \Bbb{Z}. $$

Answer (score 35):

We have $100$ people at a dance class. How many ways are there to divide them into $50$ dance pairs of $2$ people each? (Of course we will pay no attention to gender.)

Clearly there is an **integer** number of ways. Let us count the ways.

We solve first a *different* problem. This is a tango class. How many ways are there to divide $100$ people into  dance pairs, one person to be called the leader and the other the follower?

Line up the people. There are $100!$ ways to do this. Now go down the line, pairing $1$  and $2$ and calling $1$ the leader, pairing  $3$ and $4$ and calling $3$ the leader, and so on.

We obtain each leader-follower division in $50!$ ways, since the groups of $2$ can be permuted. So there are $\dfrac{100!}{50!}$ ways to divide the people into $50$ leader-follower pairs to dance the tango.

Now solve the original problem. To just count the number of democratic pairs, note that interchanging the leader/follower tags produces the same pair division. So each democratic pairing gives rise to $2^{50}$ leader/follower pairings. It follows that there are $\dfrac{100!}{2^{50}\cdot 50!}$ democratic pairings.

Answer (score 18):

Combinatorial argument:

The number of ways to arrange the digits $1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,\ldots, 50,50$ in a row is $\frac{100!}{2^{50}}$.

This is clearly a multiple of $50!$, since we can perform any of the $50!$ permutations on the set of 50 elements.

Comment: nice for combinatorial argument!

Comment: It's not so clear to me. How does a permutation of 50 relate to a permutation of 100?

Comment: @Mark If you jointly permute the $1$s, $2$s, and so on ...

Answer (score 8):

$$100!=(1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots 99)\cdot (2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdots 100),$$

where

$$(2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdots 100)=2^{50}\cdot (1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdots 50)=2^{50}\cdot 50!$$

so

$$(50\cdot 2)! = 2^{50}\cdot 50!\cdot (1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots 99)$$

---

More generally 
$$(m\cdot n)! \, =\,  m^{n}\  \cdot\  n!\ \cdot\ \prod_{(k,\, j) \ =\ (1,\,1)}^{(n,\, m-1)}\,  (m\cdot k-j)$$
Your case is $n=50, m=2$ and the product on the right is a natural number.

Answer (score 6):

Prove $51\cdot 52\cdots 100$ is divisible by $2^{50}$. Hint: Count how many multiples of 2, 4, 8... there are in the former expression.

Answer (score 5):

From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17916/how-come-the-number-n-can-terminate-in-exactly-1-2-3-4-or-6-zeroes-but-n) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141196/highest-power-of-a-prime-p-dividing-n), we have that the highest power of a prime $p$ dividing $n!$ is given by
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\dfrac{n}{p^k} \right\rfloor$$
Hence, the highest power of a prime $p$ dividing $\dfrac{n!}{m!}$ is given by
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\dfrac{n}{p^k} \right\rfloor - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\dfrac{m}{p^k}\right\rfloor$$

I trust you can finish it off from here.

Answer (score 2):

for the number of multiples of $2$:

$$100 = 52 + 2(n_1 - 1)$$
$$n_1 = 25$$

for the number of multiples of $4$:

$$100 = 52 + 4(n_2 - 1)$$
$$n_2 = 13$$

for the number of multiples of $8$:

$$96 = 56 + 8(n_3 - 1)$$
$$n_3 = 6$$

for the number of multiples of $16$:

$$96 = 64 + 16(n_4 - 1)$$
$$n_4 = 3$$

for the number of multiples of $32$:

$$96 = 64 + 32(n_5 - 1)$$
$$n_5 = 2$$

for the number of multiples of $64$:

$$64 = 64 + 64(n_6 - 1)$$
$$n_6 = 1$$

To get the number of $2$'s as factors, add all the $n$'s up, which yields $50$.

This should cancel the $2^{50}$ at the denominator, and thus prove that the expression is an integer.